# Git commit in terminal opens VIM, but can't get back to terminal

Tags: git, vim, terminal, command-line-interface, commit

Trying to learn GitHub at the moment and doing this [Git essentials tutorial](https://tutsplus.com/course/git-essentials/) over at nettuts. I'm on the lesson about making commits.

The teacher types `git commit` and it opens VIM as his editor (I'd also like to know how to make it open up in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) 2 instead) anyways it opens in VIM and I add in 1 line saying this is my first commit and hit save.

Next it then prompts me to save the output to the desktop, something I did not see in his screencast. Now I'm still in VIM and not sure how to get back to 'normal' terminal :(

I couldn't figure it out so I just exited the terminal and relaunched it, did git commit again and had some warning messages about duplicates! Not sure if I need to `(E)edit` anyways or `(A)abort`.

**git status**

[image]

**vim**

[image]

**message** when I reopen terminal and do git commit again

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using git commit -a with vim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098742/using-git-commit-a-with-vim)

Comment: @Kokodoko yeah I just commit with `git commit -m 'my message'` now, that's it :) no need for an editor, never needed to use 1, only needed 1 liners.

Comment: @LeonGaban short commit messages are okay for the first commit but from them on you should try to adopt the technique of having a short subject and then detailing what actually happened in that commit.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93144/exit-vim-more-quickly

Answer (score 417, accepted):

To save your work and exit press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> (w for write and q for quit).

Alternatively, you could both save and exit by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>

To set another editor run `export EDITOR=myFavoriteEdior`on your terminal, where `myFavoriteEdior` can be `vi`, `gedit`, `subl`(for sublime) etc.

Comment: Te set the editor permanently you can use: git config --global core.editor myFavoriteEditor

Comment: `:q!` if you don't want to save your changes.

Answer (score 44):

not really the answer to the VIM problem but you could use the command line to also enter the commit message:

```
git commit -m "This is the first commit"
```

Answer (score 24):

You need to return to *normal* mode and save the commit message with either

```
<Esc>:wq
```

or

```
<Esc>:x
```

or

```
<Esc>ZZ
```

The <kbd>Esc</kbd> key returns you from *insert* mode to *normal* mode.
The <kbd>:wq</kbd>, <kbd>:x</kbd> or <kbd>ZZ</kbd> sequence writes the changes and exits the editor.

Answer (score 17):

Simply doing the vim "save and quit" command `:wq` should do the trick.

In order to have Git open it in another editor, you need to change the Git `core.editor` setting to a command which runs the editor you want.

`git config --global core.editor "command to start sublime text 2"`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on setting the editor to sublime text. I did run into one problem though, I had to set a `--wait` flag: `git config --global core.editor "subl --wait"`. This prevents `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.`

Answer (score 17):

This is in answer to your question...

> *I'd also like to know how to make it open up in Sublime Text 2 instead*

**For Windows:**

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe'"
```

Check that the path for `sublime_text.exe` is correct and adjust if needed.

**For Mac/Linux:**

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

If you get an error message such as:

> error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.

Create the alias for `subl`

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Again check that the path matches for your machine.

For Sublime Text simply save `cmd S` and close the window `cmd W` to return to git.

Comment: That's a symbolic link, not an alias. Aliases are strings which get replaced by your shell in command contexts, though you should generally prefer shell functions over aliases.

Answer (score 1):

Like all well-behaved terminal applications which invoke an editor, `git` respects the value of the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables. If neither of these are set, it will commonly fall back to something like `vi` (though on some platforms you might find yourself in `nano` or worse).

There are plenty of existing answers telling you how to quit `vim`, and even edit in `vim` if you really want to.

On Unix-like platforms, you can set `EDITOR` just for the duration of a single command:

```
EDITOR=emacsclient git commit
```

or you can define it for the remainder of your shell session:

```
export EDITOR=emacsclient
```

Add this to your `.profile` or similar to set it at login time for all sessions.

(For `emacsclient` in particular, you want to run <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> `server-start` in your currently running Emacs instance.)

To not use an editor at all, just pass your commit message as an argument to `-m`. Most Unix shells will let you pass in a multi-line string. Usually, you want the first line to summarize the entire commit (this is what is displayed e.g. by `git log --oneline`) and by convention, there should be an empty line after that to separate it from the rest of the message.

```
git commit -m 'Small fixes

Refactored all 1,365 source files by hand'
```

(Many shells will display a `PS2` prompt, typically just `>`, while you are inside a multi-line quoted string.

```
[master] (venv) your usual shell prompt$ git commit -m 'Small changes (return)
> (return)
> More text' (return)
```

The lack of such simple obvious conveniences is one of the many, many, many reasons to avoid Windows.)