# What is the way to save and quit editing in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I was stuck in windows cmd when I try to use `git commit -a` after I enter the message I dont't know how to save and quit.

Comment: What do you mean "save"? You either commit or not, there's no way to "save"

Answer (score 1):

After you have typed in your message, you have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> (for leaving insert mode) and then

```
:wq
```

This has been discussed here: [VIM for Windows - What do I type to save and exit from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708645/vim-for-windows-what-do-i-type-to-save-and-exit-from-a-file)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you have some difficulties to use vim to write your commit message, you should configure an editor more in the habits of windows users:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/773973/717372