# How to launch and edit a file from Git using Notepad++?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, notepad++

I have set up Notepad++ as my default editor as in this topic:
[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

with this command:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Now, I'm working through a Ruby on Rails tutorial. On one step, the author uses the command:
$mate README.markdown to launch his TextMate editor and edit the readme file.

**My question is, now that I have set up Notepad++ as my default editor, what is the equivalent command that I should use to launch Notepad++ and edit the file?**

Note: I'm a beginner with this Git and Ruby on Rails. Please go easy on me! Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to launch your text editor from the command line. People tend to do that in tutorials because it's easier to understand (or because they like to do everything from the command line). You can also just double-click on the file you want to edit, and then if Windows says "What program should I use to open this?" then of course choose Notepad++.

Comment: Sure, but that's way more effort. It's much easier now that I've added notepad++ to my windows path variables.

Comment: @MatrixFrog Hi, I know it have been passed a long time since this post was created, but I want to address exactly the problem I'm confronting with which is related some how to your answer. You said files can be edited just by double clicking them when using git. How do you do that? The Sublime editor pops up the "Unable to save..." error and Notepad++ doesn't even allow me to type in it. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe README.markdown
```

And since you'll probably want to use notepad++ a lot from the command line, you may want to [alter your PATH](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) to include its root directory, so you don't need to write the full path each time.

Answer (score 1):

Add notepad++.exe to your Windows path enviromental variable( the whole path), this option is in computer, right click, advance system setting enviromental variables.
After from command promp just do:
    notepad++ markdown.README

You could also just use the whole path to notepad.exe everytime but that gets old, just learn how to edit your enviromental variables in windows.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks very much! Now, here's a question: Is there a way to just type 'npp', instead of 'notepad++'?

Comment: @Flux: sure: `doskey npp=notepad++ $*` defines the alias in a DOS session.

Answer (score 0):

You must first add Notepad++ as the main program. On Git Bash

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\Notepad.lnk' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

And then you will be able to create the file by writting

```
start notepad README.md 
start notepad++ README.md
```