# How do I remove an invalid remote I added in Git?

Tags: git

Here's the line I fired:

```
git remote add Nakor git://github.com.nakor/CherryTomato.git
```

I made a mistake and the command should have been:

```
git remote add Nakor git://github.com/nakor/CherryTomato.git
```

When I try to run the second command, I get this error:

```
fatal: Remote Nakor already exists.
```

Which is understandable. How can I edit the endpoint the remote `Nakor` is pointing to?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use the `set-url` subcommand of git remote:

```
git remote set-url Nakor git://github.com/nakor/CherryTomato.git
```

Comment: There's a typo in this answer - you shouldn't have the `--` in `--set-url` - it's just `git remote set-url Nakor git://github.com/nakor/CherryTomato.git`

Comment: This is the new way of doing it: git remote set-url <name> <newurl> [<oldurl>]

Answer (score 9):

When all else fails:

```
git config --edit
```

Under...

```
[remote "Nakor"]
```

...edit the line...

```
    url = git://github.com.nakor/CherryTomato.git
```

Comment: It opens up a Vim terminal, so now I have **two** problems. :D Any way to edit this on a normal text editor? I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that (Windows). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10564/78845) on how to configure your editor on Windows.

Comment: P.S: Vim is a [normal](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:normal) text editor... you should give it a try sometime!

Comment: I would hardly call Vim a normal text editor (in regular English sense). Also, I use Emacs. :)

Answer (score 5):

From github help [Removing a remote](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-a-remote/):

```
git remote -v
# View current remotes
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
destination  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
destination  https://github.com/FORKER/REPOSITORY.git (push)

git remote rm destination
# Remove remote
git remote -v
# Verify it's gone
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/OWNER/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Answer (score 1):

`git remote --help` tells all. In this instance, use `git remote set-url ...`.