# How to undo a "git remote add" statement?

Tags: git

I initialized a repository and added files and folders, and I commited. Now I launched this statement :

```
git remote add edm-fdm-backend <url_of_remote_repository>
```

I want to undo it. How to do that ?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove an invalid remote I added in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730611/how-do-i-remove-an-invalid-remote-i-added-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not mistaken can't you just use `git remote rm`? https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-a-remote

Answer (score -2):

git reset - cmd will undo staged files

Comment: OP didn't add "changes" but a reference to a remote. `reset` won't change that, and have other unintended consequences. I guess you must have read a bit too hastily, we all do that once in a while ^^