# My command line locks up when making a commit with GIT

Tags: git, command-line, vi

Learning GIT.  I tried committing a group of files, below you can see where I got to.

Asking for the commit comment/message but once I get to this screen, I am not able to input any text, everything I try, it will not let me enter any text into the window once it gets to this screen.

I am using the msysGit version with a program called Console 2 which is just a wrapper holding the msysGit command line tool

Any ideas why it would do this

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Looks like vim... pressing `i` does not change to insert mode?

Comment: @Felix Kling hitting `i` did in fact get me a cursor to type at, can you tell how to get out of that mode or submit once done typing?

Comment: I suggest to learn the basic vim commands. To get to command mode (leave insert mode), just press `ESC` and to save the commit, type `:wq` which *w* rites to the file and *q* uits the editor.

Comment: Press `i`, type your commit message, hit `Esc`, then type `:wq`. You can read vim tutorials to learn more about this. Try `vimtutor` command.

Comment: @Felix Kling  I do not have VIM

Comment: @Mostafa that worked, I don't have VIM installed though, does Git have vim built in or something?

Comment: @jasondavis: I assume the `msysGit` environment comes with vim.

Comment: @FelixKling, most likely. After all you need something to edit commit messages.

Comment: @jasondavis No, you're using `vi`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git is using the "Vi" text editor by default. You need to add this to your Git config file:

```
nano ~/.gitconfig
```

This file may be blank if you do not have one yet. Add this line and then save using Ctrl-X:

```
git config core.editor "nano"
```

Nano is a more straightforward to use text editor for what you want to do.

If you don't have nano installed on your platform (as is the case in standard installs of Windows 7), you can optionally use [Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows), or try [this setup program](https://github.com/blog/975-gitpad-write-your-commits-in-notepad) to use standard Notepad instead.

Comment: it is not obvious that `nano` is available on the platform.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 if that means anything

Comment: I'm thinking nano is something I need to install

Comment: You will need to install an editor of your choice, and replace "nano" with that instead. This question explains how to do the same thing with Notepad++: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows

Comment: how to reset this to initial default value?

Comment: Remove the line you just added from your `.gitconfig`.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `EDITOR` to something you're used to before invoking git (or use `git config` to set `core.editor`). Or learn to use `vi`.

Alternatively, provide message from the command line

```
git commit -m 'this is the commit message'
```

Answer (score 2):

What you see is git opening `vim` for you to edit the commit.

If you prefer other editor you can change the editor by setting:

```
export VISUAL=<your-editor>
export EDITOR=<your-editor>
```

All you need to do in that screen is to type a commit comment and save it, it will proceed with the commit (in whichever editor it appears).

Comment: or `GIT_EDITOR` for the sake of completeness :)

Comment: I don't have VIM installed so maybe it is something else? the colors are from ym console wrapper `Console 2`

Comment: Well git uses whichever editor is your default, you can change it to your preferred editor by setting the `EDITOR` variable in your environment. Btw, all you need to do in that screen is to type a commit comment and save it, it will proceed with the commit.