# How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?

Tags: git, editor, default, sublimetext, git-config

I have a problem setting Sublime Text 2 as the `core.editor` with `git`.

I've read through every post I could find addressing the problem, but still nothing is working for me. I am running Windows.

I have done:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe'"
```

and tried that with various arguments like `-m`.  When I open my `.gitconfig`, this is what is in there:

```
[user]
    name = Spencer Moran
    email = smoran02@gmail.com
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe'
```

If I go to Git and type:

```
README.markdown --edit
```

the README file opens in Notepad, not Sublime Text.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong or how I could fix this?

Comment: If you're typing _only_ `README.markdown --edit` in cmd.exe, `git` isn't involved at all. Change your file associations in windows if you want that to work.

Comment: A general FYI for most of the answers below: `-w` means "Wait for the file to be closed before returning," and `-n` means "Open a new window." Source: http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/command_line/command_line.html

Comment: My favorite settings for using Sublime Text 3 as my git editor: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits/48212377#48212377

Answer (score 387, accepted):

### Windows

#### Sublime Text 2 (Build 2181)

The latest [Build 2181](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-build-2181) just added support for the `-w` (wait) command line argument. The following configuration will allow ST2 to work as your default git editor on Windows. This will allow git to open ST2 for commit messages and such.

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

#### Sublime Text 3 (Build 3065)

[Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (Build 3065) added the `subl.exe` command line helper. Use `subl.exe -h` for the options available to you. I have `hot_exit: true` and `remember_open_files: true` set in my Sublime Text user settings. I have found the following to git config to work well for me.

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```

---

### Mac and Linux

Set Sublime as your editor for Git by typing the following command in the terminal:

`git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`

---

With this Git config, the new tab is opened in my editor. I edit my commit message, save the tab (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and close it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>).

Git will wait until the tab is closed to continue its work.

Comment: Personally, in addition to setting my editor as @jrotello suggests, my ST2/git experience improved a lot when I add the following options to my ST2 settings:

{
 "hot_exit": false,
 "remember_open_files": false,
 "close_windows_when_empty": true
}

Comment: @Sandy Can you explain? I'm kind of fond of these settings and I'd like to know the flip side

Comment: Note that the above path uses forward slashes instead of backslashes. Using backslashes causes it to fail (even when stored with `c:\\program...` in the .gitconfig).

Comment: @Phrogz: I was able to get it working in my .gitconfig with the following syntax: `editor = 'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 2\\sublime_text.exe' -w`

Comment: For me, this will open a new tab if sublime text is already open.  Closing the tab, doesn't let git know its done.  I've tried --multiinstance, but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: note that when `hot_exit` is false and the lights went out all unsaved work will begone!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @David: On Sublime Text 3 (3059) at least, adding -n works for opening a new window - found at http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

Comment: Actually, using "-n -w", git doesn't seem to be able to tell that the sublime text window closed (if I have an existing sublime window open at least).  "-w --multiinstance" still seems to work the best, though in the new sublime window any existing tabs are re-opened.  It seems they can safely be ignored.

Comment: @David: I'm using the same settings as up in the first comment from Sandy and it seems like your scenario is working for me.  I get a nice fresh window and closing the tab or window works.  (For me, I'm OK with those settings in general use.)

Comment: On Win8.1, using ST3 + Git version 1.9.4-preview20140611, after adding the program to my path and restarting I can launch ST3 via "git commit" successfully with commit info in a file named "COMMIT_EDITMSG". However, Git, immediately on file launch, says "Aborting commit due to empty commit message." - saving and closing ST3 after entering a commit message does nothing in Git.

Comment: I got it to work under Windows by using only `editor = subl.exe -w` and adding the Sublime Text directory to the path environment variable.

Comment: @kleinfreund when you say that you used `editor = subl.exe -w` do you mean Powershell or Git Bash?  I ran this in both but it's resulting in a sytax error- is there anything that I need to add before or after the command?  Also- can you explain what I should do to add the Sublime Text directory to the path environment variable?

Comment: All, I am using Git Bash on a Windows machine I'm running `git config --global code.editor "'C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe' -n -w -m"` but when I run git commit it's opening in the Notepad.  Before adding the -m flag it was opening in the Git Bash editor. I have downloaded Sublime 3 and the exe file is called "sublime_text.exe". I have not done anything else (for example, I have not changed the environment variables). Any thoughts?

Comment: I had trouble with subl.exe never exiting (windows 10 RS4/sublime 3126) no matter the flags. Oddly enough using the regular sublime_text.exe with -w -n worked.

Answer (score 104):

You can use this command on Mac and Linux:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

Comment: Actually, the recommendation on Mac these days is to symlink subl to somewhere in your $PATH and set your editor to 'subl -w'.  It's in the official docs.

Comment: The docs I referred to are: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Comment: The docs say to use `subl -w`, but if you have other tabs open this won't work correctly. I've found `subl -n -w` works better since it opens a new window.

Comment: @iano if i do that should i close tab or close window to commit? close window didnt work

Comment: This opens an empty document in sublime for me until I followed these instructions: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html but changed the path from Sublime Text.app to Sublime Text 2.app

Comment: I had to use ```ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/``` to create the symlink for ```subl```first. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25154529/1505341).

Answer (score 36):

For **Mac** & **Sublime Text 3**:

If `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"` doesn't work, use this `git config` command:

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w"
```

Note: it does *not* contain escaping backslashes.

Comment: This is the right way to set it. Thanks for that.

Comment: You my friend saved me big time, vim gives me the creeps.

Comment: Or you could just follow the instructions on how to add `subl` to your command line > [Docs](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html#mac)

Answer (score 19):

For Mac OS X in the file ~/.gitconfig under [core] I had to put this code to solve the issue on my end.

```
editor = /Applications/Sublime\\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl  -n -w
```

This was when subl was working fine but git was unable to access it. And was displaying these errors

```
subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
```

Comment: This is what did the trick for me after having tried others solutions, thanks

Answer (score 7):

what worked for me in cygwin/zsh:

in /usr/local/bin create subl_git file

```
#!/bin/bash
/cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe -w -n `cygpath -w $@`
```

in gitconfig:

```
editor = /usr/local/bin/subl_git
```

Comment: excuse my newbie question but how do I access the gitconfig?  Is this different than running `git config --list`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that just lists them out. you ned to edit your gitconfig

Comment: I had a space in my user folder so I used a modified -`"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe" -w -n "\`cygpath -d -w "$@"\``

Answer (score 6):

With Sublime Text 2 and the following configuration, **if nothing happens when you close the git commit's comment file :**

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

If the git commit doesn't finish when you close the COMMIT_EDITMSG comment file in Sublime, I've found this is probably because you are running CMD in administrator mode (and have a Sublime Text already opened in non admin mode). I had the same problem and it worked for me when I **started** my **CMD in normal mode.**

Ps : just wanted to answer to the problem @david pointed out in the accepted answer's comments, but I couldn't post comment since I'm new here... so I've made a new answer, because I think this can be useful to some people encountering the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Do you know of a solution?

Comment: @ScottWegner Just launch your CMD in non-admin mode, as a workaround. You don't need to be in admin mode to run git commands. However, If you really need to be in admin mode, then I didn't find solution for this, except open another CMD instance.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up. I end up with elevated shells because my development environment requires admin-mode for other tools (Visual Studio), thus I run my entire shell elevated. I think I'll explore only elevating the tools that need it.

Comment: @ScottWegner I personally use [Cmder](http://gooseberrycreative.com/cmder/) (the full version even includes msysgit). It allows mulitple instances of CMD, bash or other Shells, in a unique window with tabs. You can launch some tabs in admin mode and others in normal mode. I usually have one tab dedicated to git and other tabs for my other tools. Maybe you would be interested in giving it a try. It's a great tool!

Comment: re: admin mode - i think the trick is that your shell and sublime have to be using the same privileges. i.e. if you're running your terminal elevated and sublime is also elevated it works smoothly.

Answer (score 5):

I just successfully made it with the help of PowerShell (command line tools for windows, which is also be use as the default command line on GithubforWindows)

Just make a folder "WindowsPowerShell" on "C:\Users\%username%\My Documents".
Then, create a file called "profile.ps1".
Make sure that you have the correct file extension, .ps1 and not .txt.
inside the profile.ps1, put this line to set an alias command:

```
Set-Alias subl 'c:\program files\sublime text 2\sublime_text.exe'
```

Make sure the sublime directory on your machine is correct.
You can also see the configuration details in [here](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_profile_ps1.htm).

Now, I can edit files with Sublime Text 2 via PowerShell command just by typing:

```
subl filename
```

Hopefully this is usefull...

Comment: To open the current folder in Sublime Text 2, you can use:
    `subl .`

Comment: For Sublime Text 3, use the new subl.exe:
`Set-Alias subl 'c:\program files\sublime text 3\subl.exe'`

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same problem with **git editor in Windows** this evening, and finally I've got it.

You'll need to set your editor path with the **bash syntax and using the DOS 8.3 format to avoid spaces**:

This doesn't work (for me):

```
git config --global core.editor "C://Program files/Sublime Text/sublime_text.exe"
```

This do:

```
git config --global core.editor /C/PROGRA~1/SUBLIME~1/sublime_text.exe
```

You can get the DOS 8.3 name for a directory with **dir /x**

Answer (score 3):

On **MacOS(Mojave)** below is working for me for **Sublime 3**:

`git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl -n -w"`

Answer (score 2):

For Windows, try this

```bash
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just struggling with this for some reason, none of the examples above quite worked for me. This was my solution however:

```
 git config --global core.editor "'c:/<path to sublime>/sublime_text.exe' -w $*"
```

You specifically need the `' '` around the path and the `$*` at the end of the args, all in `" "`.

Answer (score 1):

For MAC Users I can say for Sublime use the following:

First Check the .gitconfig file using command:

1. `cd ~`
2. `ls -la`
3. `cat .gitconfig`

Now one can add this configuration:

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -wl1"
```

Where `l1` will tell to start at line 1.

Answer (score 1):

If you are Mac User, then here is how:

```
git config --global core.editor '/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl'
```

Answer (score 1):

well, i had some trouble invoking notepad++ from gitbash even after setting it as my core.editor.

i got it all solved by appending the below line to my .bashrc file in my gitbash installation directory.

```
alias npp='winpty "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"'
```

so, i can invoke notepad++ with the alias "npp". i feel this can help you if you change the directory to the respective editor you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if you are installing git, you can select other editor and give the following command line.
C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe -w
[image: Installer Image]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 I have found the following solution works:

```
git config --global core.editor "C:/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe -n -w"
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen any instances of updates regarding Windows allowing Git installation to actively pick Sublime Text as your default text editor without all the sturm und drang of the original override codes...
[image: Sublime Text shown as option in (re)installation of Git]

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 with sublime text 4
You can carefully edit your `.gitconfig` to this:

```
[core]
    editor = \"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text\\subl.exe\" -w
[user]
    email = Your@email.com
    name = Your Name
```

Edit the line editor line to this path so git can find subl 4.

The doble `\\` Are needed for escape the backslash character.

The `.gitconfig` file is found on your Root profile directory eg: `C:\Users\YourUsername\.gitconfig`