# Subl command not working - command not found

Tags: macos, sublimetext2

I'm having difficulty getting this set up. I fixed my `.bash_profile`, and created the symlink using the following command from the Sublime website:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Yet, when I input that command I get:

```
ln: /Users/my_username/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

It appears my terminal is looking at the wrong place for the file? Why is it trying to point to a `bin` folder on my home directory?

Comment: Make sure that the `~/bin` directory exists. `ln` won't automatically create it.

Comment: Thanks for commenting I appreciate that. So I've created the bin directory and it contains the 'subl'. However the code is still not recognized.

Comment: Applications Documents    Library      Music        Public       dotfiles
Desktop      Downloads    Movies       Pictures     bin
~ :> cd bin
bin :> ls
subl
bin :> subl --help
-bash: subl: command not found
bin :>

Comment: After ln -s "....", avoid the quotes. Do it as: `ln -s /App......`

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Create the symlink in `/usr/local/bin` instead of `~/bin` and make sure that `/usr/local/bin` in in `PATH`.

```
$ ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/.
$ echo $PATH
```

If you don't find `/usr/local/bin/`, then add the following lines to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc:`

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/; export PATH
```

Comment: So I have tried this, you can see the 'subl' in the /usr/local/bin yet the command still fails me. It exists in two places now however, the username/bin and the /usr/local/bin  '~ :> cd /usr/local/bin
bin [master] :> ls

npm                        sub
oid2name                   subl
pg_archivecleanup          vacuumdb
pg_basebackup              vacuumlo' I removed some of what was in there to not go over character limit.

Comment: can you do a ``which subl`` and paste the output?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping I have managed to solve this issue!

Comment: I just used the finder to locate the subl file and place it in my usr/local/bin, when i opened the contents of the app in finder i discovered the subl file was missing! i must've screwed it up somehow, so i deleted, reinstalled, and moved it over manually.

Comment: for Sublime Text 2: ln -s /Applications/Sublime\ Text\ 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/.

Comment: It's ridiculous that a folder that's already on the PATH variable doesn't actually exist on my harddrive when the computer is shipped to me.

Answer (score 70):

This solved my Sublime terminal (`subl`) command issue after battling for a while on Yosemite:

```
sudo su
rm /usr/local/bin/subl
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
exit
```

Here is [the source](https://gist.github.com/jadaradix/8fbfb52a942fe31b7354).

Comment: Me neither could get it going without su. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Just tried this (on Yosemite) but no luck. Even restarted terminal and checked my path..

Comment: I'm getting this error:

`sh-3.2# rm /usr/local/bin/subl`
`rm: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory`
`sh-3.2# ln -s "/Applications/Sublime` `Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl`
`ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory`

Comment: Steps to resolve for me: 1) `sudo su` 2) `cd /usr` 3) `mkdir local` 4) `cd local` 5) `mkdir bin` 6) `cd ~/` 7) run the sym link

Comment: why do we need to use sudo su?

Comment: Thank you very much! I just had to change ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl

to

ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/sublime

Comment: I've added sym link without quotes, this fixed it

Answer (score 14):

You could just add the following to the shell config file .bash_profile or .zshrc (Apple replaced bash with zsh as the default shell in macOS Catalina):

```
alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"
```

These are the steps to edit `.zshrc` and save the changes (press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and `:wq!` to save and exit):

```
$ cd ~
$ vim .zshrc
$ source .zshrc
```

To verify that it works, try the following and it should open up Sublime Text.

```
$ subl .zshrc
```

Answer (score 13):

"[Launch Sublime Text from the command line on OSX](https://gist.github.com/adrianorsouza/df4759b0583dcd112da4)" worked for me. I use Sublime Text 3 and only had to copy and paste the commands below to the command-line. I did this at the root level

```
$ cd ~
```

- If you're using Sublime Text 3 copy then paste this to the command line:

  ```
  // Sublime Text 3
  $ ln -sv "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
  ```
- If you're using Sublime Text 2 copy then paste this to the command line:

  ```
  // Sublime Text 2
  $ ln -sv "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
  ```

Now test it out to see if it works:

1. Open a new file from the command line:

   ```
   $  subl test.rb  // it should open new file test.rb in Sublime Text
   ```
2. Open a project folder:

   ```
   $ subl dir/myProject // opens a new folder inside Sublime
   ```
3. Launch Sublime app:

   ```
   $ subl // launches Sublime
   ```

To open Sublime Help for more detailed options use:

```
$ subl -h // Sublime help
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Sublime Text 2 try this:

```
$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

or, if your path is in /usr/bin/ instead /usr/local/bin:

```
$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 6):

My similar problem was solved simply by omitting the quotes. So if you're working with:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/sub
```

I instead did:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl ~/bin/subl
```

Comment: Can confirm that this worked for me too. I tried the former first but didn't work. The latter did though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

While **sarbottam's answer is the proper way** to do it, if you're lazy like me, and use subl to just do an `subl .`, you can add an alias to your ~/.bash_profile

```
alias subl="/Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl"
```

and either open a new terminal window or run the .bash_profile

Answer (score 3):

For **Sublime Text 4** and **Monterey**:

```
ln -sfv /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using MAC m1 chip. None of the answer above worked for me. But I find this one worked.

```
alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"

# IN CLI
$ cd ~
$ vim .zshrc
$ source .zshrc
$ subl .
# Now it should work! Try restarting the terminal as well if you need to!
```

Source: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/shell/subl+command+not+found+mac

Answer (score 1):

At my end `subl` was working fine but git was unable to access it. And was displaying these errors

```
subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
```

---

For Mac OS X in the file ~/.gitconfig under [core] I had to put this code to solve the issue on my end.

```
editor = /Applications/Sublime\\ Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl  -n -w
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried several combinations using `sudo` and also including or excluding leading `/` and escaping spaces in the `Sublime\ Text.app` package.

What worked to create the desired symlink was:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

I did not have to use `sudo` or modify `$PATH`.

For reference, I am on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.

`echo $PATH` currently (and without any modification by me) shows the following:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

You can tell if this worked by typing `which subl` immediately after running the `ln` command above. If you don't get a line of output showing you where Bash found your `subl` command then you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

First, make sure you are in home folder:

```
cd ~
```

**Step 1**: Remove the `/Users/Ram/bin/subl` directory by using following command line:

```
rm -rf /Users/Ram/bin/subl
```

**Step 2**: Create this folder again using following command line:

```
mkdir /Users/Ram/bin/subl
```

**STEP 3**: use the following command to create a symbolic link to sublime:

```
sudo ln -sv "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

(using `sudo` before this command overrides permission issues)

**Step 4**: Now you can test if `subl` works:

```
subl test.py
```

This should open up sublime with new `test.py` file created.

Answer (score 0):

I'm documenting this because it worked on my machine and might fix the problem for people who see "file already exists` when they run the command suggested in sarbbottam's answer. I'm not sure I can fully explain it so I may use the wrong terms.

When I copy/pasted sarbbottam's command, my terminal reported that the file already existed. I tried copy/pasting several Stack Overflow answers to this problem into my terminal, so I had symlinks called `subl` and `sublime` in my `/usr/local/bin` directory. I could see the file when I listed all files in that directory with `ls -a`. I tried to open the `subl` directory in a text editor, and it said that the file didn't exist.

I deleted the `subl` symlink in `/usr/local/bin`, ran the command, and it worked.

I think I accidentally made one for Sublime Text 2 or something, and just figured I'd be overwriting the last one which was not the case.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with having multiple symbolic links to the same target. I removed my link "subl" and my link "sublime" still works.

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded MacOS Catalina version10.15 on a new iMac and following the Sublime documentation found that the following with double quote does not work for me:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

I instead did:

```
ln -s /Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/subl
```

and it worked.

ATTENTION: this is the code worked on my iMac - MacOS Catalina 10.15, and I copy/pasted the working line directly from my machine. If you find other code working, please add another answer and specify your machine configuration. Or simple comment below. DO NOT EDIT THE CODE SECTION, ESPECIALLY ADDING THE DOUBLE QUOTE FOR THE WORKING LINE. THANKS!!

Comment: People: Please do NOT edit code section for this answer, as this is the code worked on my iMac - MacOS Catalina 10.15, and I copy/pasted directly from there. If you find other code working, please add another answer and specify your machine configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you've received the `No such file or directory` error on the M1 or ARM64 Apple architecture:

1. Make sure your copy of `Sublime Text.app` is in the `/Applications` directory.
2. If you hate Vim, you may make edits to your `zshrc` file with Nano, instead:

   nano ~/.zshrc
3. Within the resulting editor, you may add the following line:

   alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"
4. Then simply press `ctrl+x` key to exit the interface.
5. You will be prompted inline to save the changes. Press `Y` to retain the edits.
6. Write `source.zshrc` and then press `return`.
7. Finally, you can write `subl .zshrc` and then press `return`.

This should result in seeing the contents of `.zshrc` right within Sublime Text.