# Remove error message and launch correct editor in Git

Tags: git, sublimetext2

I'm using Git on Windows 7 and Sublime Text 2 as my editor.

In .gitconfig, there is this line: `editor = subl -n -w`

That is an incorrect entry, because I had tried to set Sublime Text as the editor for Git by using the command `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"`
as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/).

but, in haste, I had not read the full instructions and didn't notice that I needed to have installed subl first. Also, this only works on a Mac!

On top of that I had mistyped the command as `subi -n -w`

So now, when I do:

```
git config --global --edit
```

I get the error:

```
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subi -n -w'
```

I assume that's because I had previously mistakenly mistyped the command (see above)

So then I tried setting the editor with:

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/git-config-core-editor-how-to-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git-on), which inserts the following line in `.gitconfig`:

```
editor = 'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w
```

I have also tried manually editing that line to:

```
editor = C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe -w
```

but I still get the error when doing `git commit` or `git config --global --edit`

I have tried to use unset:

```
git config --global --unset-all core.editor
```

and then re-input Sublime Text as the editor (manually and using command line). I still get the error message and Sublime Text is not launched (for git commit). How do I get rid of the error message and successfully launch Sublime Text as the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that, during your numerous attempts to get the original mistake corrected, you inserted an offending (non-printable) character in the `.gitconfig` file?

One thing I might try is:

1. Create a new git repository in a dummy directory
2. View/Copy the `.gitconfig` from **that** project into your current project
3. Edit the `.gitconfig` with the correct path/filename to execute Sublime

I do not profess to know this is the solution.  It is just a creative approach to solving your problem.

Please report your results for others who may stumble across this in the future (it may very well even be ME! < smile >).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by opening up the config in the project directory and spotting that the following line was in there:

```
editor = subi -n -w
```

(i.e. the erroneous line)

I simply removed it and problem solved, i.e. Sublime Text now responds to the system wide `.gitconfig` line:

```
editor = 'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w`
```

I hadn't quite understood local project configuration, so thanks to @Thom Parkin for leading me on a path to the solution