# Sublime as text editor for Git Bash

Tags: git, git-bash, text-editor, git-config

I've been trying to change the default text editor to Sublime Text 3.

I've seen about a dozen different was to do it include multiple ways here but I can't seem to change it. I've tried `git config --global core.editor "'/c/Program Files/Sublime Text 3/subl.exe' -w"` I've tried `C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\subl.exe" -w` I've also tried using single quotes because it was mentioned in [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git).

I got to the point where I just wanted to change the text editor to anything and I used`git config --global core.editor "notepad.exe" -w` and `git config --global core.editor "emacs" -w`

I assume I use `subl FileName.txt` to execute it. when I've tried `emacs FileName.txt` and `notepad`
because I've tried so many times, when I use `git config --list` It displays four different properties in `core.editor` 3 of them are the Sublime variations I've seen online and one is my notepad attempt. `Vim` is still the only thing that works.

I haven't tried to make PATH changes but I've seen some talk of that but I heard that for those who know what they're doing. Now it started telling me `warning core.editor has multiple values error: cannot overwrite multiple values with a single value Use a regexp, --add or --replace-all to change core.editor`. And I've got no clue how to do that.

I know this isn't supposed to be this difficult. I think this is just a glaring oversight on my behalf but I've been at this for hours.

Comment: Do you have any local config (`git config --local -l`) which might override *all* your --global attempts?

Comment: No I haven't attempted changing that. I've found a that creating a `.bash_profile` file and adding `alias subl="/c/Program\ Files/Sublime\ Text\ 2/sublime_text.exe"` to it works for what. I saw similar answers but I'm pretty confident I didn't see any that used `.bash_profile`. Thank you so much for your response.

Answer (score 0):

> I saw similar answers but I'm pretty confident I didn't see any that used .bash_profile

Actually, this [thread mentions a similar option](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=4461)

> Using Sublime, I created `.bash_profile` in $HOME

But one of the difficulties comes from a path with spaces and special charaters (`()`).
I have a SublimeText3 installed in `C:\prgs\sbt\` (using the portable version [Sublime Text Build 3083 x64.zip](http://c758482.r82.cf2.rackcdn.com/Sublime%20Text%20Build%203083%20x64.zip)), and it is easier to reference in a `git config` setting.

A simple `git config core.editor "C:/prgs/sbt/sublime_text.exe -n -w"` is enough for me.

Comment: Thank you. That thread on the Sublime Forum was the exact one I found. Thanks for the tip on portable version of the software. I'll keep that in mind  for the future.