# ''subl' --wait' doesn't work while merging branch [Git]

Tags: git, macos, github, git-merge

I followed few articles over the [pretty](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log) attributes on [Git 2.10](https://github.com/blog/2242-git-2-10-has-been-released) release note. Going through which upgraded the git to 2.10.0 and made changes to global `.gitconfig` resulting as follows -

```
[filter "lfs"]
    clean = git-lfs clean %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge %f
    required = true
[user]
    name = xyz
    email = abc.def@gmail.com
    signingkey = AAAAAAA
[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/xyz/.gitignore_global
    editor = 'subl' --wait   <!--this is where its failing I guess--!>
[difftool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = opendiff \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\"
    path = 
[mergetool "sourcetree"]
    cmd = /Applications/SourceTree.app/Contents/Resources/opendiff-w.sh \"$LOCAL\" \"$REMOTE\" -ancestor \"$BASE\" -merge \"$MERGED\"
    trustExitCode = true
[alias]
    lg = log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative
[color "diff"]
    old = red strike
    new = green italic
```

But now when I try and execute git commands as follows, I get no progress details on the console or proper message display.

> ```
> ➜  automation git:(branch1) git pull origin master
> From https://github.com/XYZ/automation
>  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
> Auto-merging pom.xml
> Auto-merging test/pom.xml
> 'subl' --wait: subl: command not found
> error: There was a problem with the editor ''subl' --wait'.
> Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
> ```

---

***Update : Post the comment from @Arvin for duplicacy***

If I follow the solution there to change my default git editor using

```
git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"
```

I still get

> subl -n -w: subl: command not found error: There was a problem with
>   the editor 'subl -n -w'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git)

Comment: @Arvin - i've explained why its not a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This post should help - [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git)

Below is what it states -

#### Sublime Text 2 (Build 2181)

The latest [build 2181](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-build-2181) just added support for the **-w** (wait) command line argument. The following configuration will allow ST2 to work as your default git editor on Windows. This will allow git to open ST2 for commit messages and such.

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 2/sublime_text.exe' -w"
```

#### Sublime Text 3 (Build 3065)

[Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) (Build 3065) added the `subl.exe` command line helper. Use `subl.exe -h` for the options available to you. I have `hot_exit: true` and `remember_open_files: true` set in my Sublime Text user settings. I have found the following to git config to work well for me.

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```

With this git config the a new tab is opened in my editor. I edit my commit message, save the tab and close it (`CTRL+w`). Git will wait until the tab is closed to continue its work.

Comment: have updated the question and the tag(osx) after your comment. This also doesn't seem to be solving the problem.