# Why won't Sublime Text Editor open when I type git commit?

Tags: git, terminal, sublimetext3

This was working before. I'm completing Udacity's How to Use Git & GitHub.

Before when I would type "git commit" it would open up the Sublime Text Editor - I could edit text at the top - and then I could save it, then type in git status to see what the changes are.

The next step is to add the changes to the staging area. However, now when I put in git status or git commit I get a very long response like this:

```
    davidshinabarger (master *) ~ $ git commit
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
    modified:   Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/vcs.xml
    modified:   Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/drawable/buttonshape.xml

Untracked files:
    .AndroidStudio2.1/
    .CFUserTextEncoding
    .Trash/
    .Xauthority
    .adobe/
    .android/
    .bash_history
    .bash_profile
    .cache/
    .config/
    .dropbox/
    .eclipse/
    .emulator_console_auth_token
    .gitconfig
    .gradle/
    .lesshst
    .local/
    .oracle_jre_usage/
    .p2/
    .rnd
    .ssh/
    .tooling/
    .vagrant.d/
    AndroidStudioProjects/
    Applications/
    Colorsublime-Plugin/
    Desktop/
    Documents/
    Downloads/.localized
    Downloads/1337.tmTheme
    Downloads/2112 (1).tmTheme
    Downloads/2112.tmTheme
    Downloads/Adventure_Time.tmTheme
    Downloads/Colorsublime-Plugin-master.zip
    Downloads/Colorsublime-Plugin-master/
    Downloads/Gitter-1.177.dmg
    Downloads/Package Control.sublime-package
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.gitignore
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/compiler.xml
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/copyright/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/encodings.xml
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/gradle.xml
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/.idea/misc.xml
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/.gitignore
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/build.gradle
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/proguard-rules.pro
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/androidTest/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/java/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/layout/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/mipmap-hdpi/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/mipmap-mdpi/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xhdpi/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxhdpi/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/values-w820dp/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/main/res/values/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/app/src/test/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/build.gradle
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/gradle.properties
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/gradle/
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/gradlew
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/gradlew.bat
    Downloads/PikachuFlipper/settings.gradle
    Downloads/QuickenDownload_1485026374285.qfx
    Downloads/QuickenDownload_1485182052495.qfx
    Downloads/Sublime Text Build 3126.dmg
    Downloads/VirtualBox-5.1.14-112924-OSX.dmg
    Downloads/bash_profile_course
    Downloads/bash_profile_course (1)
    Downloads/git-2.10.1-intel-universal-mavericks.dmg
    Downloads/hukl-Smyck-Color-Scheme-fc16622.zip
    Downloads/hukl-Smyck-Color-Scheme-fc16622/
    Downloads/iTerm2-3_0_13.zip
    Downloads/osx-terminal-themes-master.zip
    Downloads/osx-terminal-themes-master/
    Downloads/terminal-sexy.txt
    Downloads/transactions.qfx
    Dropbox/
    Library/.localized
    Library/Accounts/
    Library/Android/
    Library/Application Support/
    Library/Caches/
    Library/Calendars/
    Library/Compositions/
    Library/Containers/
    Library/Cookies/
    Library/Dictionaries/
    Library/Favorites/
    Library/FontCollections/
    Library/Fonts/
    Library/Google/
    Library/Group Containers/
    Library/IdentityServices/
    Library/Input Methods/
    Library/Keychains/
    Library/LanguageModeling/
    Library/LaunchAgents/
    Library/Logs/
    Library/Mail/
    Library/Messages/
    Library/PreferencePanes/
    Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
    Library/Preferences/Adobe PNG Format CS6 Prefs
    Library/Preferences/Adobe Photoshop CS6 Paths
    Library/Preferences/Adobe Photoshop CS6 Settings/
    Library/Preferences/Adobe/
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.1/
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/inspection/
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/keymaps/
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/IntelliLang.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/androidStudioFirstRun.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/debugger.renderers.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/debugger.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/diff.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/dimensions.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/editor.codeinsight.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/editor.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/extensionsRootType.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/feature.usage.statistics.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/file.template.settings.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/find.recents.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/find.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/git.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/gradle.run.settings.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/ide.general.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/images.support.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/instant-run.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/jdk.table.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/keymap.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/laf.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/options.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/other.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/project.default.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/recentProjects.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/runner.layout.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/security.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/statistics.application.usages.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/stubIndex.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/ui.lnf.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/updates.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/usage.statistics.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/web-browsers.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/window.manager.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/options/window.state.xml
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/port.lock
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/tasks/
    Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio2.2/user.token
    Library/Preferences/ByHost/
    Library/Preferences/CD Info.cidb
    Library/Preferences/DSPPublishingServer.plist
    Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2016.3/
    Library/Preferences/Macromedia/
    Library/Preferences/MobileMeAccounts.plist
    Library/Preferences/QuickTime Preferences
    Library/Preferences/SafariCloudHistoryPushAgent.plist
    Library/Preferences/callservicesd.plist
    Library/Preferences/callservicesd.plist.TgCTKyl
    Library/Preferences/callservicesd.plist.WiXROpt
    Library/Preferences/com.Breakpad.crash_report_sender.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.adobe.CSXS.3.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.adobe.Photoshop.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.adobe.crashreporter.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.adobe.mediabrowser.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.android.Emulator.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ActivityMonitor.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.AddressBook.plist.x8jVGJU
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.AppleMultitouchTrackpad.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Automator.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Automator.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.BezelServices.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.BluetoothFileExchange.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreGraphics.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.CoreGraphics.plist.3wkhseq
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.DVDPlayer.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FaceTime.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FileStatsAgent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FinalCut.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FinalCut.UserDestinations.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FinalCut.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontBook.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.FontRegistry.user.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.GEO.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist.d0LHqjE
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.InputMethodKit.UserDictionary.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.QuarantineEventsV2
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices/
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Maps.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.MassStorageCamera.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.PTPCamera.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.PhotoBooth.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Photos.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Preview.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ProblemReporter.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.PubSubAgent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickLookDaemon.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.QuickTimePlayerX.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.SafariCloudHistoryPushAgent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ServicesMenu.Services.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.SetupAssistant.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Spotlight.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Stickies.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.SystemProfiler.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.TelephonyUtilities.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist.KGofA4Z
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.TextEdit.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.UserAccountUpdater.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.accountsd.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.airplay.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.airport.airportutility.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.appstore.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.archiveutility.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.AudioMIDISetup.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.InfoHelper.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.aulab.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.audio.aulab.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.bird.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.bookstoreagent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.bootcampassistant.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.calculateframework.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.cloudpaird.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.commerce.knownclients.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.commerce.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.coreservices.uiagent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.client.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboardlauncher.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.diskimages.fsck
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist.zBlclAz
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad.plist.Bw3LO3h
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.facetime.bag.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist.5jN0xNy
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist.HfVqDVo
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist.P75xEUB
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.frameworks.diskimages.diuiagent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.gamed.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.gamed.plist.ZNezT85
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.garageband10.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.help.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.helpd.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.helpviewer.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iApps.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iCal.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.AIM.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Jabber.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iChat.Yahoo.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iMovie8.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iPod.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.Gracenote.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.eq.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunesHelper.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.iWork.Pages.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ibooks.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.icbaccountsd.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.icloud.fmfd.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.identityservicesd.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.deviceproperties.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.ess.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.madrid.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.ac.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.callhistorysync.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.activity.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.auth.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.encryption.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.continuity.tethering.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.icloudpairing.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.idsremoteurlconnection.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.idstransfers.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.maps.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.multiplex1.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.phonecontinuity.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.screensharing.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.ids.service.com.apple.private.alloy.sms.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.imessage.bag.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.FaceTime.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.imservice.ids.iMessage.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.inputmethod.CoreChineseEngineFramework.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.inputmethod.SCIM.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.internetaccounts.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.internetconfigpriv.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.java.util.prefs.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginitems.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.mediaaccessibility.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.menuextra.battery.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.menuextra.clock.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.messaging.expire.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.metadata.SpotlightNetHelper.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.preference.general.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.extensions.ServicesWithUI.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.preferences.extensions.ShareMenu.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.print.add.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.quicklook.satellite.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.quicktime.plugin.preferences.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.registration.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.scheduler.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.screensaver.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.KCN.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3.keysToRegister.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.5cgosbd
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.6ELGQYT
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.JyvthXE
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.Mlymuog
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.XyxeUlJ
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.pqaWqMW
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.spaces.plist.qD3hBel
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.syncserver.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.systempreferences.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemsound.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccess.plist.ud5wkk1
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarning.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.wifi.keychain-format.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.apple.xpc.activity2.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.aspyr.borderlands2.steam.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.bitgapp.eqMac.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.bittorrent.uTorrent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.coconut-flavour.coconutBattery.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.cycling74.Soundflowerbed.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.divx.DPC.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.divx.DivXComponentManager.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.divx.Setup.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.divx.WebPlayer.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.github.GitHub.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.github.GitHub.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.google.Chrome.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.google.Keystone.Agent.plist.lvok1s7
    Library/Preferences/com.google.android.mtpviewer.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.google.gct.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.google.musicmanager.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.jetbrains.intellij.ce.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.makingfun.dominion.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.Java-Updater.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.oracle.java.JavaAppletPlugin.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.oracle.javadeployment.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.rogueamoeba.audiohijack3.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.sublimetext.3.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap.helper.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.tinyspeck.slackmacgap.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.trolltech.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.valvesoftware.steam.helper.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.valvesoftware.steam.plist
    Library/Preferences/com.ynab.YNAB4.LiveCaptive.plist
    Library/Preferences/fr.handbrake.HandBrake.plist
    Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.bluej/
    Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.oomph.setup.installer.product.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.eclipse.platform.ide.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.macosforge.xquartz.X11.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.openoffice.script.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.openoffice.script.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.shiftitapp.ShiftIt.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc.LSSharedFileList.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.videolan.vlc/
    Library/Preferences/org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBox.plist
    Library/Preferences/org.virtualbox.app.VirtualBoxVM.plist
    Library/Preferences/pbs.plist
    Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.calendar.plist
    Library/Preferences/widget-com.apple.widget.weather.plist
    Library/PubSub/
    Library/Safari/
    Library/Saved Application State/
    Library/Saved Searches/
    Library/Screen Savers/
    Library/Services/
    Library/Spelling/
    Library/StickiesDatabase
    Library/SyncedPreferences/
    Library/Usertesting/
    Library/VirtualBox/
    Library/WebKit/
    Library/iTunes/
    Movies/
    Music/
    Pictures/
    Public/
    Sunshine-Version-2/
    VirtualBox VMs/
    bash_profile_course
    eclipse/
    git-completion.bash
    git-prompt.sh
    pappu-pakia/
    things.zip

no changes added to commit
```

I would like to have Sublime Text Editor open up when I type in git commit, not display this long display. 
What is happening exactly? 
What do I need to do?

I already checked and made sure that I followed [all the instructions here on how to make Sublime the Text Editor and everything.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git)

Thank you so much in advance.

EDIT: Trying to follow instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=22&v=2AOLeYpVHzk

Comment: you haven't told it what you want to commit yet? did you miss a `git add` step in there somewhere? or a -a flag?

Comment: @KevinB you're totally right, I missed a previous step in one of the previous videos. I went back into it and was able to figure it out. Still unsure though, why are there so many untracked files present? Any ideas why those are showing up?

Comment: It seems that you have initialized your whole home folder as a git repository, that seems like a terribly bad idea.

Comment: Hey, @1615903 that's exactly what happened. I got it all figured out, I'll add my answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the ouput it says "no changes added to commit". I guess you need to stage the changes you want to commit first?

Comment: Yes? I'm trying to follow the instructions specifically in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=22&v=2AOLeYpVHzk . At 0:15 it instructs me to type git commit to pull up the sublime text editor, but when I type that in I just get the response in the previous post.

Comment: In his video she seems to have staged the files "cake-recipe.txt" and "frosting-recipe.txt" before the video. I'd guess the staging is missing in the video or the staging was done in a previous idea.

Comment: Hey @Ray, you're totally right. I went back a video or two and found the answer. Completed the next step, but it says in the next video that after commiting the changes and checking the status that I'm getting a message "nothing added to commit but untracked files present" instead of "nothing to commit, working directory clean". But I think that's a separate question I can search on here.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer that another student helped me out with. Very surprisingly simple:

"It looks like you’ve initialized git on your root directory—a common mistake. You can remove git tracking from your home directory by deleting the .git folder. It's hidden so make sure you turn on Show hidden files, folders and disks option. Make sure you create a new directory for your project and cd into it before initializing git."

Thanks, everybody.