# Invoke sublime editior in git

Tags: windows, git, windows-10

How to invoke sublime text editior in git in windows 10.
I do this using  alias np="/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" but this is temporary i want to invoke it as np permanently

Comment: Save it into `~/.bashrc` or such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append your alias to the end of `~/.bashrc` so it's loaded every time bash starts.

```
echo 'alias np="/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/associating-text-editors-with-git/#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor-1)

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:/program files/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```