# How to open Sublime Text 3 editor with git commit

Tags: git, sublimetext3, git-commit

I have already configured Sublime Text 3 as my text editor for git Bash. Sublime successfully opens when I type `subl 'filePath'`

However, when I try a git commit, the text editor fails to open and outputs the following error:

```
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... subl -n -w: subl: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'subl -n -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

I have added to files to the staging area and am ready to commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/associating-text-editors-with-git#using-sublime-text-as-your-editor-1)

You can set your default editor in Git to use Sublime Text 3.

1. Install Sublime Text 3.
2. Open Git Bash.
3. Type this command:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/sublime text 3/subl.exe' -w"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! May you please elaborate on what was going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I used the below command on **Mac** and it worked

```
$ git config --global core.editor "'/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl' -n -w"
```

Comment: Basically identical to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47294229/341994 and other existing answers.