# How to remove VIM as my Mac editor vs sublime

Tags: macos, vim, sublimetext3

How to remove VIM (completely) and change my mac command line editor to sublime?

I've spent the last three hours reading the same links on "how to remove VIM" only to get "how to remove MacVIM and reinstall it fresh" Or "How to remove Vim so I can reinstall it on Ubuntu"

My old laptop was fortunate to have a friend remove it but my new machine still has it installed.

I wish VIM would die in <strike>"words redacted to excessive profanity"</strike> dumpster fire while a hobo <strike>"words redacted to excessive profanity"</strike> to put out the fire

I've lost way too many hours trying to learn that outdated neckbeard elvish piece of UX trash so I want it gone. No, I'm not touching emacs.

Please tell me there is a way I can switch to sublime or am I permanently cursed to have this confusing black screen of death pop up when I try to git push or git tag stuff?

My original goal was to tag a git and push it but vim comes up and I can't figure out how to speak elvish.

I've been using PyCharm for a few years and love the interface but I need to dig deeper and a TDD Django book for class uses the terminal, it wants me to git -a "comments" so I need your advice.

So now I can't learn TDD Django because vim, MacVim and eMacs users flood the internet but I can't remove it nor figure out how to work it.

I've tried `brew uninstall macvim` which doesn't work because I have vim not macvim

I also tried `sudo uninstall vim` no luck as this is zsh mac not ubuntu

I tried `brew uninstall vim` to get `No available formula or cask with the name "vim"`

I've searched SO five times and keep getting the same links.
Alternates I've tried
`brew uninstall ruby vim`

per this post https://superuser.com/questions/1096438/brew-upgrade-broke-vim-on-os-x-dyld-library-not-loaded  I tried, no luck.

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies perl
brew uninstall vim
brew install vim
```

I'm not installing an app to remove another one, thanks but no thanks Nektony.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't know how to sidestep VIM, my solution for most things is to google it for a while and try a few things. If that doesn't work I unwind the changes in git with PyCharm and look for more help on StackOverflow.

Unless you know how to solve this it's like telling someone to get to a village following the Hindi roadsigns when they speak Russian.

I per the comments I clicked [How can I make Sublime Text the default editor for Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951275/how-can-i-make-sublime-text-the-default-editor-for-git) I also tried `git config --global core.editor "subl -n -w"` which kinda helps as it flashes scrolls past a bunch of menus but it didn't open sublime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to remove Vim from your machine. Instead, [tell your system and your tools to use Sublime Text as default editor](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/command_line.html). After you have followed that tutorial, which I must point out is part of Sublime Text's documentation, you should have a system-wide `subl` command that you can use instead of `vim`. For that, you need to add those lines to your shell configuration file:

```
export EDITOR=subl
export VISUAL=subl
```

which will be honoured by basically every CLI program susceptible to open a file in a text editor.

You can even add the following for good measure:

```
export GIT_EDITOR=subl
```