# Is there a way to make sublime as core.editor (git) on Mac

Tags: git, sublimetext3, editor, git-bash, text-editor

I have researched back and forth on this issue and so far nothing has worked. I'm unable to open sublime while using git using a command such as sublime. or command line tool named subl.
I have used another command on git but it shows in config --list but it is not opening.

Comment: @sandeep-kumar AFAIK the program is called `subl`, not `sub`. Please fix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9408117/1978365