# How do I rebase while skipping a particular commit?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase, git-interactive-rebase

Is there a way to rebase a branch onto another while skipping a particular (conflicting) commit on the other branch?

For example, I want to rebase `mybranch` onto `master`, but master contains a commit that will conflict with the commits in master, so I prefer to undo that commit completely.

```
-o-o-o-o-o-x-o-o-o-o master
     |
     o-o-o-o mybranch
```

x marks the conflicting commit.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i master
```

An editor will open and you will have a list of commits like this:

```
pick b8f7c25 Fix 1
pick 273b0bb Fix 2
pick 6aaea1b Fix 3
```

Just delete the commit you want to skip. It will be omitted while rebasing your branch onto master.

**P.S.** If you cannot see the editor, please, refer to this question for solution: [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564/1065190)

Comment: The editor only shows the commits on mybranch.  Is there a way to bring it up showing all the commits; i.e. from the tip of mybranch, down to master, and up to the tip of master?

Comment: Do you want to delete the commit in your branch or in master? The second option if pretty insafe and will cause troubles to all other developers who have ``master`` as their upstream.

Comment: I want to skip a commit on master (I added a diagram as part of my question).  I'm not worried at the moment about `master` on the upstream.

Comment: When checkout master and do ``git rebase -i <commit-you-want-to-omit>^`` and remove it in the editor.