# git-rebase--interactive: line 237: nano: command not found

Tags: git

I was following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history) post and came across the error in the title when attempting

`git rebase -i origin/master`

the code again:

`/user/libexec/git-core/git-rebase--interactive: line 237: nano: command not found`

`could not execute editor`

Comment: Is the text editor 'nano' installed on your system? What OS are you working on?

Comment: @reto I am not sure I am very new to using git, I am following that guide because I think I left a password in my local git repository. 

Windows 7

Comment: @reto sorry but I have no idea. I just installed git from [here](http://git-scm.com/) and installed it with default settings. No fancy stuff on my end.

Comment: answer to this post can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/773973/2842568

Comment: @VladNiktin Thanks! That worked I'm using Notepad++ now :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

the git rebase -i wasn't told what editor to use,
use this following command to solve the problem.

export GIT_EDITOR=nano (global)

or

git config --global core.editor "nano" (local)

replace 'vim' in place of 'nano' for vim editor