# Git rebase and Vim editor

Tags: git, vim, rebase

I have learned a lot about git rebase and have now started using it in my windows 8 environment.Problem is that when I type command `git rebase -i HEAD~3` it pops up a vim editor with couple of options like pick,squash etc Now I don't understand what to do in this editor since I do not know how to use Vim here.Please guide me how to do it.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just configure different editor. See [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows).

The answer there is a bit longish; the most relevant command is

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

The editor command has to be in single quotes if it contains a space (as it usually does). The alternate workarounds are using DOS path (`C:/PROGRA~1/Notepa~1/...` or somesuch) or creating a wrapper script in some path that does not have spaces.

In either case, use forward slashes for path separator.

You don't want to use plain notepad though. At least notepad++ or such that can handle Unix newlines, encodings and such.

Comment: Now I have configured notepad++ and it does well that is it shows the same text here on notepad++.exe what I am worried now is what to do in that editor?

Comment: @khan: It's explained in the comment below, or in the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) (look for section titled "interactive mode").