# notepad++ not working in Git Bash

Tags: git, notepad++

I'm on windows 7 64 bit os and I'm trying to setup notepadd++ as my tex teditor in Git Bash

here's what I've already done

1. git config --global core.editor "\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
2. set up notepadd++ in my system variables

now, when I try to edit a file (i.e. notepad++ myfile), it says command not found. even when I try just to open notepad++, it says command not found

I'm totally new in Git and I think I'm totally lost in what I'm doing. What I basically want is to get my notepad++ work with Git Bash

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to figure out why `notepad++ somefilename.ext` doesn't work from "git bash" window on Windows? If so, you should show the result of `echo $PATH` from your git bash window in your question (or in a comment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a combination of double and single quotes, as in "[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431003/6309)":

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Note also the use of '`/`' instead of '`\`' in this case.

Comment: Ive already tried all of those options but still not working for me. I know i can open files in windows explorer but its really frustrating to not get this simple thing working :(

Comment: @Maai try it in a non-git-bash, that is in a regular cmd session, launched with `git-cmd.bat` which is included in your msysgit installation (https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat)

Comment: This could work with **Windows' version of Git**, but not with **Cygwin's version**, because Cygwin's Git would execute Notepad++ with Cygwin's path to the file: `notepad++.exe /home/user/repository/file.extension`. I'm sure Windows Notepad++ won't find such file. Even if you have you repo outside Cygwin's directories, it would look like this: `notepad++.exe /cygdrive/d/repository/file.extension`.

Comment: @Daw true, but it has been years since I've last used the cygwin version of git.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert file path from the Unix/Cygwin format, which Git on Cygwin produces, to the Windows format, which Notepad++ on Windows uses. Otherwise Git on Cygwin will execute Notepad++ like this:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/Notepad++.exe /home/user/repository/file.extension`
```

It's obvious that Notepad++ won't find such file.

See my answer to question [How to add split Git diff hunk from cygwin using Windows editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171337/how-to-add-split-git-diff-hunk-from-cygwin-using-windows-editor/25185337#25185337). There is described how to configure it properly.

Comment: I think "git bash" is a third way to run and control Git on Windows, and it's not CygWin at all. The tutorial I just now watched on "git bash" showed a "mingw32" window started up.

Comment: Yes, but in fact, *mingw32* **is** Cygwin, because it was forked from Cygwin long time ago (from Cygwin version 1.3 AFAIK). But it's possible that Git compiled in *mingw32* environment was modified to use Windows' paths.

Answer (score 1):

in my case worked adding single quotes around the windows path, due to spaces it was giving me the same error message, so I used:

```
git config --global core.editor "'c:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

and it started working

Answer (score 0):

try this:

1. find the place which the `/etc/bash.bashrc` is in windows
2. add a notepad++ alias at the end of bash.bashrc, like this:

```
    alias npp=\
    "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

3. you can use `npp ~/.gitconfig` to test