# There was a problem with the editor ''C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'

Tags: git, notepad++

This is the code,Im using the ubuntu terminal to run.

```
(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin: 1: C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe: not found
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$ git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin: 1: C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe: not found
error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$
```

I tried the solution on this link [notepad++ not working in Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24226362/notepad-not-working-in-git-bash) , but Im unable to resolve the error.

This is the error I get on `git commit`

`error: There was a problem with the editor ''C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'`

How do I resolve this

EDIT:
output from `git config --list`:

```
(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$ git config --list 
user.name=Pra 
user.email=mask@abcs.com 
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true 
core.bare=false 
core.logallrefupdates=true
```

Comment: You seem to be on Windows, not Ubuntu.

Comment: No ubuntu app on windows. Ive mentioned ubuntu terminal, I didnt say the OS is Linux

Comment: Does it help if you change the path to the editor to `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe`? (or: `"/mnt/c/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`) If not, please post the output from `git config --list`

Comment: @Luuk You mean like `editor = "'/mnt/c/Program\'" `?

Comment: without the single quotes, and the complete path

Comment: `(base) pra:~/my_project/demo$ git config --list
user.name=Pra
user.email=mask@abcs.com
core.editor='C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true`

Comment: Please next time use [edit] (like I did just a moment ago)

Comment: The statement after `core.editor` should start Notepad++. I doubt if that is working on your site.  Change that setting until Notepad++ is starting, with the parameters you currently have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I removed the `editor` from config and it worked.