# How to open files in Notepad++ from Git Bash?

Tags: git, notepad++

What i need is command in Git Bash which will open files (txt,html,php..) in Notepad++. Just like when i type `notepad test.txt` test.txt opens in notepad, i want similar command, let's say `npp test.txt` which will open test.txt in Notepad++. I'm using Win7(64).

Comment: http://danlimerick.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/git-for-windows-tip-setting-an-editor/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows/773973#773973

Answer (score 1):

I create a file called `npp` in my Notepad++ installation directory.  `npp` has the following in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
"c:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin "$*"
```

Then add the Notepad++ installation to your PATH.

Now, in git bash you can use a command like:  `npp foo.txt` to start up Notepad++ editing foo.txt.

Answer (score 1):

updated:
Best way so far add notepad++ to the path and

```
$ start notepad++ [file path]
```

or you can add

```
alias npp='winpty "C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"'
```

to your .bashrc file in your home directory.

Worked much better for me with Git Bash.