# Git commit , not able to commit the changes from editor window

Tags: git, git-commit

I am new to GIT and trying to do some of its basic operations, working with Windows.

I am successfully able to add a new file using command:- `git add "filename.txt"`
When I try to commit is using command:-- `git commit "filename.txt"` , a new editor window opens and there I add the commint message. I am not able to come out of it.
If I do ctrl+c, I get to the start point but changes are not committed.

I do not want to use -m to add message.

How can I save the added message in the editor window?

Comment: Is the message you're seeing after the non-commit "Aborting commit due to empty commit message."?

Comment: No, I am adding the message but how to come out of the editor?

Comment: What happens if you save and exit the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every commit needs a log entry. You probably need to type a reason for the commit such as "first commit" in the popup window.

You can choose your text editor and it sounds like you haven't set your editor.

If it's `vi` that is popping up, you use `i` to insert, and `escape` `:wq!` to write to file.

Comment: Seems you havent read my problem completely. If I do not give the -m flag, editor window opens and there I am giving complete message,but  how to come out of the editor window?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't set your editor. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Mixie no problem. Please mark my answer as the solution, so I can get points.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to change the default editor. Thank You

Comment: @Mixie see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't customize anything, it's probably a `VI` editor. After you enter the comments, and just save and exit like it's in `VI`.

```
ESC -> :wq -> Enter
```

If not, you may try to save and exit in the editor's way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was VI only, as I never worked with this.