# How to use Visual Studio Code as default editor for git?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When using git at the command line, I am wondering if it is possible to use Visual Studio Code as the default editor, i.e. when creating commit comments and looking at a diff of a file from the command line.

I understand that it won't be possible to use it for doing merges (at least at the minute) but does anyone know if it is possible to use it for looking at diff's, and if so, what command line options would be required in the .gitconfig file to make this happen?

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried an approach similar to what I have done for [Notepad++ in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows), i.e.

```
#!/bin/sh

"c:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin "$*"
```

And used:

```
#!/bin/sh

"C:\Users\gep13\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.1.0\Code.exe" "$*"
```

But this results in an error message:

```
C:\temp\testrepo [master +1 ~0 -0]> git commit
[8660:0504/084217:ERROR:crash_reporter_win.cc(70)] Cannot initialize out-of-process crash handler
Aborting commit due to empty commit message.
C:\temp\testrepo [master +1 ~0 -0]>
```

Code opens up correctly, with the expected content, but it isn't waiting on the response, i.e. clicking save and closing the window to return to prompt.

**UPDATE 2:**

I have just heard back from one of the developers working on VSCode.  Looks like this functionality currently isn't supported :-(

https://twitter.com/IsidorN/status/595501573880553472

If you are interested in seeing this feature get added, you might want to think about adding your votes here:

http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7756482-support-git-configure-diff-and-merge-tools

**UPDATE 3:**

I have been [reliably informed](https://twitter.com/shanselman/status/595604230234210304) that this feature has been picked up by the VSCode team, so I am looking forward to a future release that will include it.

**UPDATE 4:**

Thanks to @f-boucheros comment below, I have been able to get VS Code working as the default editor for commit comments, rebase, etc.  I would still  like to see if it is possible to use it as the diff tool as well.

**UPDATE 5:**

As per the accepted answer for the question, this is now possible using the V1.0 release of code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make Git use the editor of my choice for commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Answer (score 1130, accepted):

In the most recent release (v1.0, released in **March 2016**), you are now able to [use VS Code as the default git commit/diff tool](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_vs-code-as-git-editor). Quoted from the documentations:

> 1. Make sure you can run `code --help` from the command line and you get
>    help.
>
> - if you do not see help, please follow these steps:
>
>   - Mac: Select **Shell Command: Install 'Code' command in path** from the Command Palette.
>   - *Command Palette is what pops up when you press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> while inside VS
>     Code.  (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in Windows)*
>   - Windows: Make sure you selected **Add to PATH** during the
>     installation.
>   - Linux: Make sure you installed Code via our new .deb or
>     .rpm packages.
>
> 2. From the command line, run `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`
>
> Now you can run `git config --global -e` and use VS Code as editor for configuring Git.
> [image]
> Add the following to enable support for using VS Code as diff tool:

```
[diff]
    tool = default-difftool
[difftool "default-difftool"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

> This leverages the new `--diff` option you can pass to VS Code to
> compare two files side by side.
>
> To summarize, here are some examples of where you can use Git with VS
> Code:
>
> - `git rebase HEAD~3 -i` allows you to interactively rebase using VS Code
> - `git commit` allows you to use VS Code for the commit message
> - `git add -p` followed by `e` for interactive add
> - `git difftool <commit>^ <commit>` allows you to use VS Code as diff editor for changes

Comment: I also found addinng `--new-window` to the command to be helpful. This way the git operation will open in a new window.

Comment: This is answer is great.   Only problem is the code window opens under my current command prompt window.  (running code version 1.4.0)

Comment: When we talk about _command line_ we mean `Ctrl+Shift+P` ? Mine is not working (no `code --help` available) and i do not understand what means: "Make sure you selected Add to PATH during the installation" What should i do to check it?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Related: VS Code still isn't usable as a git mergetool, but hopefully that's coming: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5770

Comment: Note as of v1.1 you need to disable "hot exit" or remember to explicitly save the file before exiting vscode otherwise git won't see any changes. If you prefer to be reminded to save on exit you can disable this feature by editing your user settings: Insert `"files.hotExit": "off"` at the bottom of your config

Comment: @jrotello: According to the [Command Line documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/command-line), `--new-window` is (now) the default, so you no longer have to specify it when running from the command line.

Comment: I had to use `git config core.editor "code -n --wait"` with VS Code 1.17.2, running from external command line. Both `code` and `code --wait` got me the "Aborting commit due to empty commit message."

Comment: In Linux Mint 19, VSC displays the $LOCAL file, but displays a new empty file for $REMOTE. Both are opened in tabs instead of being displayed side by side.

Comment: Would be great if we could also: 1) Specify that ESC closes the window from the command line (so it's not a permanent key mapping) and 2) From the command line, temporarily disable the confirmation to save when exiting (always save). This would make editing quick: `Commit > Type stuff > ESC > Done`

Comment: For the difftool cmd, you might want to add `--disable-extensions` to disable all extensions or `--disable-extension <extension-id>` to disable an extension in case extensions keep raising annoying errors in the diff window. You can get the extension-id on the extension detail page like in this image https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/extension-gallery/extension-identifier.png.

Comment: @PaoloFalomo, _command line_ means from a shell. `ctrl+\`` opens it in vscode, but you could just open cmd or git bash.

Comment: @void.pointer, I think I find it just as fast to use `Commit > Type Stuff > ctrl+s (save) > ctrl+w (close tab) > Done` given that `s` and `w` are right next to each other on the keyboard.

Comment: And merge is now available as well as: [merge]
    tool = vscode
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED

Comment: If you're getting error `line 14: realpath: command not found`, use `code.cmd --wait` instead.

Comment: I was caught out on this because, at some point in time, I had defined an editor for git and forgot to use the `--global` switch and then forgot all about it.  I tried everything in this answer and none of it worked. In the end, `git config --unset core.editor` solved it and made everything work again. Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68096451/how-to-use-vscode-1-5-as-default-editor-for-git/68096965#68096965

Comment: Adding `editor = code --wait` into the `[core]` section of my `~/.gitconfig` file--that's all I needed! Upvoted. Works great on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 122):

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

or

```
git config --global core.editor "code -w"
```

verify with:

```
git config --global -e
```

Your configuration will open in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: For the check, it should actually be `git config --global - e`

Comment: ```git config --global core.editor "code --wait"``` did the trick

Answer (score 55):

For what I understand, VSCode is not in AppData anymore.

So Set the default git editor by executing that command in a command prompt window:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe' -w"
```

The parameter `-w`, `--wait` is to wait for window to be closed before returning.  Visual Studio Code is base on Atom Editor. if you also have atom installed execute the command `atom --help`. You will see the last argument in the help is wait.

Next time you do a `git rebase -i HEAD~3` it will popup Visual Studio Code. Once VSCode is close then Git will take back the lead.

Note: My current version of VSCode is 0.9.2

I hope that help.

Comment: Thanks! What is the significance of the `-w` and where did you find that documented?

Comment: Good point. It's coming from Atom -w is for Wait. I edited my answer.

Comment: I have set this up, and I am happy to say that it is working.  If I could get this to work now as Visual Studio Code doing the diffing of the files as well, that would be great! :-)

Comment: this now seems to no longer work with the latest update to VS Code. Do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @GaryEwanPark: You need to launch *code.cmd* (or *code* on \*nix) from the *bin* subdirectory instead, for the command line options to work. Ideally you would add the *bin* subdirectory to your %PATH% environment variable (the installer does that for you, too), and configure the editor running `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`.

Comment: Just sharing what worked for me in case it is useful to someone in the future. Sub-in your preferred editor.

```git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe'" --replace-all```

Answer (score 38):

Another useful option is to set `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables. These environment variables are used by many applications and utilities to know what editor to use. Git also uses one of them (depending on Git version) if no `core.editor` is set.

You can set it for current session using:

```
export EDITOR="code --wait"
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

This way not only `git`, but many other applications will use VS Code as an editor.

To make this change permanent, add this to your `~/.profile` for example. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables) for more options.

---

**Another advantage of this approach** is that you can set different editors for different cases:

1. When you working from local terminal.
2. When you are connected through SSH session.

This is useful especially with VS Code (or any other GUI editor) because it just doesn't work without GUI.

On Linux OS, put this into your `~/.profile`:

```
# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then # SSH mode
  export EDITOR='vim'
else # Local terminal mode
  export EDITOR='code -w'
fi
export VISUAL="$EDITOR"
```

This way when you use a local terminal, the `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable will be empty, so the `code -w` editor will be used, but when you are connected through SSH, then `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable will be a non-empty string, so the `vim` editor will be used. It is console editor, so it will work even when you are connected through SSH.

---

For the difference between `EDITOR` and `VISUAL` environment variables please see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4859/204811).

Comment: I've discovered that, with Git 2.30.1 on macOS at least, if no `core.editor` config is provided, Git uses the `$VISUAL` environment variable, rather than `$EDITOR`. So I like this answer, but I also added a line below `fi` stating `export VISUAL="$EDITOR"` to sync them up.

Comment: `GIT_EDITOR='code --wait' ` worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04; git 2.34.1; VS Code 1.68.1. Setting `EDITOR` did not, and setting `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` did not.

Answer (score 20):

You need to use command:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe' -n -w"
```

**Make sure you can start your editor from Git Bash**

If you want to use Code.exe with short path, you can do this by adding the following line to your .bash_profile:

```
alias vscode="C:/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/Code.exe"
```

And now, you can call it using only `vscode` command(or whatever you named it)

Some additional info:

> Setup will add Visual Studio Code to your
>   %PATH%, so from the console you can type 'code' to open VS Code on
>   that folder. You will need to restart your console after the
>   installation for the change to the %PATH% environmental variable to
>   take effect.

Comment: `-n` is short for `--new-window` making git open up a new editor window, and `-w` is short for `--wait`, making git wait for you to close the window again. This is the only answer that works for me, because I if I already have VS Code open `--wait` will not work without `--new-window`.

Answer (score 17):

*I'm adding an answer because all the others were not succinct enough for my liking/did not fit my exact situation. I'm running a MacBook Air 2021 with an M1 chip*

To make VS Code you default git editor in VS Code:

**Step 1**

Run the command `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"` in your command line.

**Step 2**

If you try making a commit at this stage, you might get an error that looks like this:

"hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code -w: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code -w'".

This means you don't have the shell command "code" installed in VS Code. Use (command + shift + p) to open the command centre in VS Code. Search for "code" and select "Shell Command: Install ‘code’ command in PATH". This adds "code" to your path.

**Step 3**

While trying to install "code", you might get an error that looks like this:

"EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/usr/local/bin/code'".

I don't know what causes this but a simple uninstall and re-install resolves it. To uninstall, search "uninstall" in the VS Code command centre and select "Shell Command: Uninstall ‘code’ command in PATH"

**Step 4**

Run the command `git config --global -e` to test what your new default editor is. Your config file should open in VS Code text editor

Sources:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-configure-git-to-use-vs-code-as-the-default-text-editor-ea3670ab525a

[VS Code Denied Permission unlink 'usr/local/bin/code'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004740/vs-code-denied-permission-unlink-usr-local-bin-code)

Answer (score 4):

Run this command in your Mac Terminal app

```
git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/code"
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work as you get the error message: Aborting commit due to empty commit message. A wait flag will need to be added. For example   --wait.

Comment: So weird, `code` didn't work, I needed the full path

Answer (score 3):

I opened up my `.gitconfig` and amended it with:

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Users/miqid/AppData/Local/Code/app-0.1.0/Code.exe'
```

That did it for me (I'm on Windows 8).

However, I noticed that after I tried an arbitrary `git commit` that in my **Git Bash** console I see the following message:

```
[9168:0504/160114:INFO:renderer_main.cc(212)] Renderer process started
```

Unsure of what the ramifications of this might be.

Comment: I had also tried that, however, I was getting "fatal: bad config file line 14 in C:\Users\gep13/.gitconfig" then I noticed I had backslashes, where you have forward slashes.  Changing those round made it work, but like you I am seeing the "Renderer process started" output, which actually outputs twice for me, and then shows: "[11956:0504/091108:ERROR:ipc_channel_win.cc(136)] pipe error: 109" but the commit actually seems to have worked.

Comment: Ah, interesting. It appears that my suggestion only works if you've got Code completely closed _(not very convenient!)_ before making the commit. I encounter the same error you reported in your update if Code is open.

Comment: interesting indeed. I guess that is where the -multiInst flag for Notepad++ would come into play. I wonder if there is something similar for VSCode.

Comment: Just FYI, `app-0.1.0/resources/app/env.js` appears to contain a few command-line flags that the Code executable takes. None suggest behaviour equivalent to that of `-multiInst` though.

Comment: you need to add the `--wait` flag, and the `--new-window` flag is also highly recommended, so that the commit msg/diff/whatever doesn't just show up as a new tab in an already-open editor, requiring you to close files you may still be working on in order to signal git that you're done editing.

Answer (score 3):

Good news! At the time of writing, this feature has already been implemented in the **0.10.12-insiders** release and carried out through **0.10.14-insiders**. Hence we are going to have it in the upcoming version [1.0 Release of VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Roadmap).

Implementation Ref: [Implement -w/--wait command line arg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/commit/276a1cf3079e691b75c56aa5f0fe629fc80953ac)

Comment: can you comment on how I would be able to use the diff viewer within VSCode to view diff's in git?

Answer (score 3):

In addition of `export EDITOR="code --wait"`, note that, with VSCode v1.47 (June 2020), those diff editors will survice a VSCode reload/restart.
See [issue 99290](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/99290):

> with [commit 1428d44](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/1428d44d172bf6fffddd198c71235df86b6ff0fa), diff editors now have a chance to survive reloads and this works OK unless the diff editor on a git resource is opened as the active one:
>
> [image]

(and [commit 24f1b69](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/24f1b69a901f941c4a0a327798e2f9f9058af008) fixes that)

Answer (score 3):

**I added `git bash` in `vscode terminal` as default**
**If you are lazy like me. Then I advise you to do the same as me.**

- Step1: Open setting: `Ctrl + ,`
- Step2: search `.json` --> choose file `setting.json`
- Step3: Paste the code at the end of the file but in brackets
  **`'}'`**

  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "gitbash",
  "terminal.integrated.shell.windows":"E:\app\git\Git\bin\bash.exe",

Answer (score 2):

> what command line options would be required in the .gitconfig file to make this happen?

I had to add this to my .gitconfig file for git-lense to work:

```sh
[core]
    # Make sure that interactive rebases open correctly with vs code
    editor = code -w -n
```

`-n` is optional – as Alex mentioned below it's short for `--new-window` and I find it helpful :)

Comment: As mentioned in the last answers, you may also config this setting via the CLI, with the command: `git config --global core.editor "code -w -n"`

Comment: `-w` is short for `--wait`

Answer (score 1):

[GitPad](https://github.com/github/GitPad) sets your current text editor as the default editor for Git.

My default editor for `.txt` files in Windows 10 is Visual Studio Code and running GitPad once made it the default editor for Git. I haven't experienced the problems mentioned in the question (Git waits until VS Code window is closed in my case).

(The link for the `.exe` file didn't work for me, you may need to compile the source yourself.)

Comment: What did you point at as the default editor?  I have tried to use what is described here: http://www.donovanbrown.com/post/2015/07/07/how-to-set-visual-studio-code-as-your-default-editor But that doesn't seem to want to work. Don't really want to point at a specific exe, as that will change as Code is updated.

Comment: @Gary, I didn't have to point a specific file, Code was in the list when I did `Right click` > `Open with` > `Chose another app`. I would expect it to [register itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee872121(v=vs.85).aspx) on setup (and update the registry with every update so shell can find it) but I couldn't find anything other than "Open with Code" context menu item in the registry. So I really don't have a clearer answer for this, sorry.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, I don't have code as an entry in the list that appears when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add these back slashes to previous answers, I am on Windows 10 CMD, and it doesn't work without back slashes before the spaces.

```
git config --global core.editor "C:\\Users\\your_user_name\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft\ VS\ Code\\Code.exe"
```

Comment: I was able to add with:

git config --global core.editor "'C:\Users\cbre_admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe' -w"

Answer (score 1):

In 2022 on Windows 10 you should have next path:

`git config --global core.editor "'C:\Users\<your username here>\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\code.exe' -w"`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure you can do this, however you can try these additions in your gitconfig file.

Try to replace the kdiff3 from these values to point to visual studio code executable.

`[merge]
        tool = kdiff3
    [mergetool "kdiff3"]
        path = C:/Program Files/KDiff3/kdiff3.exe
        keepBackup = false
        trustExitCode = false`

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I don't think merging will be supported, as I don't think Visual Studio Code knows how to do this, I suspect it will only be able to do diff and commit messaging.

Answer (score 0):

I set up Visual Studio Code as a default to open .txt file. And next I did use simple command: `git config --global core.editor "'C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Code\app-0.7.10\Code.exe\'"`. And everything works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

on windows 10 using the 64bit insiders edition the command should be:

> git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
>   Insiders\bin\code-insiders.cmd'"

you can also rename the 'code-insiders.cmd' to 'code.cmd' in the 'Program Files' directory, 
in this way you can now use the command 'code .' to start editing the files on the . directory

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to use Visual Studio Code as editor for Git if you can´t change your Git configuration or if you have to set `EDITOR` to another editor for some reason.

```bash
export GIT_EDITOR="code --wait"
```