# Dedicated tab for git commit messages using vscode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

When running git commit in the CLI something like the following (default) template is shown (in whatever editor is used):

```
[empty line]
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
# Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
#
# Changes to be committed:
#       modified:   Makefile
#
```

This allows the user (a) to see the list of items that are going to be affected by the commit and (b) provided a multiline message.
In particular, it is common to have a short (<72 chars) first line. An empty line and then a longer message.

When committing from within vscode, I cannot find a way of having a full-fledged editor for the commit message. All one has is something like the following:

[image]

Where a multiline message is possible but without the pleasure of an editor.

I am currently using 1.23.1.

Answer (score 0):

The commit field extends according to the amount of what is put in it.
[image]

But, vscode displaying a warning message on commit message length: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18807

Answer (score -1):

That editor is all that is necessary.
Your first line will be used as the message, which as you say should be concise.

Multiline messages (i.e. messages that include line breaks) will automatically consider the second line and beyond to be the "description" on services like GitHub.

If you'd really like to avoid using this editor, I'd recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139152/5007662).