# I was wondering how can I edit commit message with VSCODE in remote-SSH?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I want to  edit commit message like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139152

Indeed , it is use VScode as the git core.editor by `git config --global core.editor "code --wait"`

But I use remote-SSH , and cannot found  `code` to run .

Is there any way to edit Git commit message int VScode remote-ssh?

Comment: Funny, I was looking for the same feature.