# Git commit fails: "Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."

Tags: git, git-commit

When I type the git commit command to commit my file, I get this error message:

> Microsoft Visual Studio: Microsoft: command not found
>
> error: there was a problem with the core editor 'Microsoft Visual Studio'.
>
> Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: You should use `git commit` with the `-m <message>` option. because a  git commit always need a explain message. For example: `git commit -m "add the search feature"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make git use the editor of my choice for commits?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596805/how-do-i-make-git-use-the-editor-of-my-choice-for-commits)

Answer (score 3):

Check you `git config core.editor` value.
It might refer to a path with spaces in it, without quotes.

Make sure to use simple quotes when registering that editor path:
(And double quotes around the all command expression registered.
And '`/`' instead of '`\`' for the path separator)

```
git config core.editor "'C:/path/with spaces/xxx.exe' -<someoptions>"
```

That what was done when [using, for instance, Visual Studio Code as a git editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32171432/6309).

Comment: Suddenly started being a problem and this command fixed it, even though I'm using /usr/bin/vim