# How to make Atom open when I type "git commit"

Tags: git, atom-editor

When I type `git commit` Atom should  open, but it doesn't.

For the configuration on command prompt, I typed:

```
config --global core.editor "atom --wait"
```

When I type:

```
git commit
```

It says:

```
hint: waiting for your editor to close the file .......

error: there was a problem with the editor  "atom --wait"

Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: You should use git commit with the -m <message> option. because a git commit always need a explain message. For example: git commit -m "add the search feature"

Comment: but on the videos i watched, they just used "git commit" without using -m or something else.

Comment: What happens if, at the command line prompt (`$` or whatever it is), you enter the command: `atom --wait somefile.ext`? Does that work at all? If so, what does it do: does it invoke the `atom` editor and then wait for it to exit, to signal that you have finished editing the file? If not, what *does* work to invoke `atom` and wait for it to exit?

Comment: @torek hey, thanks for replying but since i couldnt get my atom work, i just deleted and installed again if i could solve. It didnt solve it, then i set my core.editor as default "vim", now its working.

Comment: I use vim myself, it's a perfectly good editor. If you do want to get atom working and use atom, follow the above idea: find out how to invoke atom from the command line. Once you know how to do that, you know how to instruct *Git* to do that. The `core.editor` setting is how you tell Git what command-line command to use to invoke your preferred editor.

Comment: thank you for your relpy. This is my first time trying to use git, because i want to know how to share codes on github. I have to learn it

Comment: Don't add "Solved" to a title. Simply mark the appropriate answer as selected. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

As it is explained in "[Git commit fails: "Please supply the message using either -m or -F option."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547405/git-commit-fails-please-supply-the-message-using-either-m-or-f-option)", you should check your `git config core.editor` value.
It might refer to a path with spaces in it, without quotes.

Make sure to use single quotes when registering that editor path,
and double quotes around all command expressions registered, along with
 `'/'` instead of `'\'` for the path separator.

```
git config core.editor "'C:/path/with spaces/xxx.exe' -<someoptions>"
```

Comment: $ git config core.editor "'C:/Users/bilim/AppData/Local/atom/atom.exe'"
fatal: not in a git directory, it gave me an error, i couldnt do it. So ill just try to watch youtube series or find some tutorials..  thanks for replying

Comment: Because you need to be in a git resository when you execute this command

Comment: @Semih Use `git --global config` ..., then you don't need to be in a git repo. I think pcampana missed the global flag in your question.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you, i just solved the problem by changing my editor to vim :) but thanks for answering to you both.