# How to exit git default text editor in JetBrains IDE console (PowerShell, but inside WebStorm IDE)

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide

I was using git in JetBrains IDE WebStorm terminal (based on Windows PowerShell). While trying to commit without a message, I got this message:

```
# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
```

I tried searching how to exit that, but nothing worked (**ESC** -> **:wq** or **ctrl+c** -> **ctrl+x** or other editor commands, but since I never set the editor, it should be Vim).
I guess that's because when I press ESC, IDE escapes the terminal and throws me to code editing window, and the editor never gets to read that ESC.

Is there any way to exit, or I have to restart the terminal?

(Please don't tell me how to change default editor, I definately will do this later)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but since I never set the editor, it should be Vim

Check what `git config core.editor` returns (from the root folder of your repository, in your IDE Powershel terminal)

That way, you will know more about the actual nature of the editor (as [illustrated here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004963019-Using-IntelliJ-as-Git-Bash-Core-Editor-on-Windows)), which can then guide you in your search to exit it.

As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73057866/how-to-exit-git-default-text-editor-in-jetbrains-ide-console-powershell-but-in/73061120?noredirect=1#comment129045654_73061120), since `git config core.editor` is empty, it is best to set it up, avoiding the default behavior.

Comment: It returns nothing: https://ibb.co/qYwRYM5

Comment: @GaussGun OK so can you configure it and see if you can retry your commit?

Comment: I'm having problems with setting atom as editor. I have it installed, but command `git config --global core.editor "atom --wait"`  stated on atom offical page is not working. GIt says *cannot spawn atom: No such file or directory*. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @GaussGun You might need to specify the full path of the exe, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61099343/6309).

Comment: thanks, needed to specify the path. But now it opens Atom in a window, and immediately I get `Aborting commit due to empty commit message.` in my terminal. I downloaded wrong Atom?

Comment: @GaussGun Did you try with `-n -w` as [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706443/git-commit-command-with-core-editor-equals-atom#comment125404410_37707106)?

Comment: I ended up with notepad++, works fine