# Setting Visual Studio Code as my Mac's default editor (including editing Git commits)

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

I am trying to configure my Mac Book Pro (OSX El Capitan 10.11.1) to use Visual Studio Code as its default editor. I have created a `~/.bash_profile` file with the following two lines

```bash
vscode () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}
export VISUAL=open\ -n\ -b\ "com.microsoft.VSCode"
```

This works for some things: I can type `vscode test.txt` at the bash terminal and up pops `test.txt` in Visual Studio Code, and if I run the command `env` I see `VISUAL=open -n -b com.microsoft.VSCode` in the list. I can even just type `$VISUAL` and Visual Studio Code opens on a new empty file.

But if I type `git commit` I get the following error

> error: cannot run com.microsoft.vscode: No such file or directory
>   error: unable to start editor 'com.microsoft.vscode' Please supply the
>   message using either -m or -F option.

So I have succeeded inasmuch as git is trying to open Visual Studio Code for me to edit my commit message but it is then failing.

What `X` should I use in the line `export VISUAL=X` in my `~/.bash_profile` file to enable git to open Visual Studio Code for commit messages?

(N.B. [How to use Visual Studio Code as Default Editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30024353/575530) is not a duplicate since Gary is on a Windows PC.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's working with the latest version 0.10.9 of VS Code

```
[core]
editor = '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron' -w
```

Test it with: git config --global --edit. remember to refresh the terminal after you have changed the config file.

Comment: Thanks Martin, do you know what the equivalent line would be on Windows?

Comment: It's close to the same
[core]
 editor = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft VS Code\\code.exe' -w
[

Comment: Strangely that didn't work for me on the PC: VS Code started fine but Git did not notice the saved commit message and aborted the commit. I'll ask a separate question

Answer (score 71):

### Add `export EDITOR="code -w"` to your shell's profile or rc file

(For example, your bash profile is accessible via `open ~/.bash_profile`)

This requires you to have the `code` binary already in your path.

If you don't have that, or don't know if you do, simply go into vscode, enter `CMD + SHIFT + P`, type *code* and click **Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH**.

Also, very helpful comment by *pompalini* below,

> remember to "refresh" terminal by closing and opening it again or resourcing your bash profile by running `source ~/.bash_profile`. Only then will the new changes in `.bash_profile` apply to your terminal.

Comment: This works, but just remember to "refresh" terminal by closing and opening it again, only then it will apply your bash_profile. Thanks

Comment: You can also run `$ source ~/.bash_profile` instead of opening and closing the terminal.

Answer (score 28):

1. In terminal

   - Type: `open ~/.bash_profile`
   - Insert: `export EDITOR="code -w"`
2. In visual studio code

   - Press: `CMD + SHIFT + P` to open the Command Palette
   - Type `install code` and select from autocomplete menu `shell command: Install 'code' in command PATH`

Answer (score 6):

1) Just add this to your *~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc:*

`code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $* ;}`

2) Then either open a new terminal or run: `source ~/.bash_profile` or `source ~/.zshrc`

After this steps, you will be able to do `code .` to open VS Code on any path

Answer (score 6):

You could also use [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti), a command line tool to select default applications for document types and URL schemes on macOS.

1. Install duti via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```bash
brew install duti
```

2. Use duti:

```bash
# Make VS Code as default editor for all text files
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.plain-text all

# Open files without extensions with VS Code as well
duti -s com.microsoft.VSCode public.data all
```

[Reference](https://patelhiren.com/blog/setting-vscode-as-default-text-editor-on-macos/)

Answer (score 3):

<s>Currently VSCode can not be used as git editor, sorry. We have this as a story on our backlog.</s>

**Update for our VS Code 1.0 release:**

This is now possible! All you need to do is to configure Code as the git editor using the newly introduced `--wait` option from the command line.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin - is the backlog public anywhere?

Comment: Not yet but we plan on making this more public.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue, This resolved it for me:

1.Just open vscode and press

`cmd+shift+P`

2.Run shell command to add code to the path (try uninstall and install code if you run into an issue"

3.Now open the terminal and run

`git config --global core.editor 'code --wait'`

test it with

`git config --global -e`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).