# vs code doesn't stop in git rebase -i middle steps after opening core editor

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code, git-rebase

First,this is **NOT DUPLICATE** from [How to use Visual Studio Code as Default Editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46962944/vs-code-doesnt-wait-for-me-during-an-interactive-rebase).

I followed that setup carefully but had other problem.

After I run `git rebae -i HEAD~3`,

It quickly prompts `Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/myBranch.` without stopping for the middle steps, while left a unsaved empty git-rebase-todo file open.

[image]

It **CAN** open the core editor normally but it doesn't wait, but I **DO** add `--wait` in gitconfig.

[image]

Any one can help me out?

Tried set sublime 3 as core editor, no luck.

Comment: Interesting question don't see a mistake. One question is this local or global config. Maybe something in the other one?

Comment: @ian Pretty sure this is global .gitconfig under ~

Comment: The question was more is there a local config? But a few things to test would be `code --help` and `git config --global -e` does it open in vs code and does the console wait?

Comment: @ian  I have checked there is no local config. This is a common problem among all my repositories.

`code --help` seems to be an invalid command.
`git config --global -e` does open the editor and wait.

Comment: not sure about this. `code --help` not working suggests to me vs code is missing in path. but then `git config...` opening just fine in vs code. not sure how this works on mac. maybe try [add to path](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac)