# How can I set VScode as core editor in git /macbook

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I cannot set Visual Studio Code as my core editor for git. When I'm trying to do the git commit I only see the info that there is a problem with editor.

```
MacBook-Air-Agata:~ agataskrzypczyk$ git config --global core.editor "/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app" --wait

MacBook-Air-Agata:~ agataskrzypczyk$ git config --global core.editor
/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app

MacBook-Air-Agata:~ agataskrzypczyk$ cd nowy

MacBook-Air-Agata:nowy agataskrzypczyk$ git commit

hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app: /Applications/Visual: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
MacBook-Air-Agata:nowy agataskrzypczyk$
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+VScode+core+editor

Comment: An alternative approach to the answers below is to set your EDITOR environment variable as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57144660/10682164) answer. Provides more flexibility in case you happen to use multiple editors for different contexts.

Answer (score 25):

I suggest you to set Visual Studio Code option to be launched from command line. For this follow the instructions in the documentation [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line).

- Launch VS Code.
- Open the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) and type 'shell
  command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH
  command.

Then try setting core editor with this command:

```
git config --global core.editor "code --wait"
```

And then I think you'll not have problems with `git commit`.

Comment: hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... error: cannot run atom: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'atom'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Comment: Worked for me! Ran `git commit --allow-empty` after the above line of code, and got no problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
git config --global core.editor "code"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation, how your solution solves the problem

Comment: Literally ran this in my cli as admin and then I typed git commit in phpstorm and it opened vs code...allowing me to type my commit message in vs code. Thank you for this.