# Trying to commit files in VS Code without luck

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, wait, commit

I have managed to create a working directory and staged the files successfully and now I wanted to move them to commits. In the terminal in VS code I have opened the folder and type git commit and it returns the following:

```
/Users/lenabeltramin/Desktop/LenasSkillshareProject(HEAD) 21:12:55 
$ git commit
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... code --wait: code: command not found
error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

How do I solve this so I can commit the files? Anyone who can guide me through this? I've been challenged to push something to GitHub for the first time and I'm a total rookie but trying my best to learn.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Visual Studio Code as Default Editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024353/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-as-default-editor-for-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+vs+code+editor

Comment: It looks like `code` is not in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you saved all files + the VS is not linked to the program (app is not running), then do:

`git commit -m 'YourTitle'`

where Title is your description of the commit.