# VSC command palette (too narrow)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there any possibility to make command palette wider?

When looking for symbol (e.g. same functions with different set of arguments) to less characters are shown to choose proper definition.

Is there any possibility to mitigate this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Visual Studio Code as Default Editor for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024353/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-as-default-editor-for-git)

Comment: I added a feature request for this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/122666

Answer (score 0):

Using standard VS Code settings looks like you can't do this, which I agree should be possible. The strange thing is that I can't find an extension too that does this, so there may be a specific reason why this can't be done at the moment. By the way you can [open an Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues) on the VSCode Github and ask the developers themself to add this feature or why seems to be missing at the moment