# Have issues with interactive rebase

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I tried using  the command `git rebase -i HEAD~2` but on trial it gives a strange message on the terminal which I don't want to be getting and I see nothing on my code editor which has been already configured to VS code as I can merge, add commit, etc.

But unfortunately the message it gives me on my terminal;

```
hint: Waiting for editor to close the file... code --wait : code: command not found

error: There was a problem with the editor 'code --wait'
```

Nothing also appears on my editor to show the commits which I wish to pick, reword, edit, fixup, and possibly even drop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Visual Studio Code as default editor for git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024353/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-as-default-editor-for-git)

Comment: Your terminal cannot find your `code` executable. Is it part of your `PATH`? Where is VS Code installed?