# How to move part of git branch to different repo?

Tags: git

Let assume that i have a git repo with commits:

```
H - add stuff
G - add stuff
F - add stuff
E - remove big files
D - add stuff
C - add big files
B - add stuff
A - initial commit
```

I want to move this branch which is master to different repo from commit F to H without the stuff from A to E. Basically the new repo would contain squashed commits from A to E plus commits F,G and H.

Update:
Based on comments i tried the following, but it ended up in merge conflicts:

```
git checkout A
git checkout -b cleanup
git checkout master
git rebase -i cleanup

pick A
squash B
squash C
squash D
squash E
pick F
pick G
pick H
```

Comment: What do you mean by "different repo"?

Comment: A new repository

Comment: New remote repo?

Comment: No, a new clean repo containing only what i need.

Comment: You can do it directly in the repo, or you can just copy to a new repo, what answer do you prefer?

Comment: I would like to transfer to new repo.

Comment: Note that no commit can ever be changed. Your new repository will have all-new commits; their *snapshots* can be the set of commits you have chosen here, but those will be new commits with different hash IDs. They cannot be combined with the original commits afterward. (This is unlikely to be an issue for you but it's worth keeping in mind.)

Comment: That said, given how small this job is, [y.rashi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330687/1256452) should work for you. To do this sort of thing with a big repository consider using `git filter-repo`.

Comment: @torek Can you please share a resource that can rewrite the history with the spcific command of `git filter-repo`?

Comment: @y.rashi: No. Filter-repo is a big Python program that lets you *write Python* to do your filtering, so it's extremely flexible. There are specific recipes included with it for specific problems, but if your problem is not one of those specific ones, you must write your own code.

Comment: "but it ended up in merge conflicts" Why did it end? Merge conflicts only end things if you stop when you get them. Don't. The correct response to merge conflicts is to _resolve_ them. Remember, merge conflicts are _not bad_. They are not an error condition. They are not a problem. They merely indicate that what's happened is beyond Git's capacity to perform _automatic_ merge. Merge conflicts are a _good_ thing: they greatly reduce the chances that Git will do something wrong while merging for you.

Answer (score 1):

[Git internally](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/git-under-the-hood/) is just a folder that contains objects that represent snapshots of the state of your files.

So the **first step** in the process is to copy your entire project including the `.git` folder (this is **crucial** you may not see it if it hidden, but it will be okay if you just copy the all project folder).

**The next step** is to operate the `git rebase` command in the copied folder like this:

```
git rebase -i <A hash in this exmple ce0e2fd>
```

You'll be presented with an interactive window like this:

```
ce0e2fd pick A initial commit
72ab3c4 pick B add stuff
8150939 pick C add big files
301c1e1 pick D add stuff
ab123c4 pick E remove big files
342d191 pick F add stuff
12ce3d7 pick G add stuff
23fd457 pick H add stuff

...
```

If you're using the default vim editor, you may need to learn how to use it, too.

**My recommendation is to use vscode**, use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30024353/how-to-use-visual-studio-code-as-default-editor-for-git) to change it to your default editor.

Interactive rebase provides instructions for your scenario, so you should change `"pick"` to `"squash"` for A till E:

```
ce0e2fd squash A initial commit
72ab3c4 squash B add stuff
8150939 squash C add big files
301c1e1 squash D add stuff
ab123c4 squash E remove big files
342d191 pick F add stuff
12ce3d7 pick G add stuff
23fd457 pick H add stuff
```

This will squash A till E into a single commit, allowing you to change the commit message.

If you're happy to use the commit message of A, you can use `"fixup"` instead of `"squash"` and you won't be prompted to update the commit message.

**In case you want to make sure that the commits A to E are completely removed and no longer accessible**, please check
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4528593) on how to prune dangling commits.

## update:

Base on the comments and our discussion, it seems you will maybe face some conflicts.

As well said [@mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt):

> "but it ended up in merge conflicts" Why did it end? Merge conflicts only end things if you stop when you get them. Don't. The correct response to merge conflicts is to resolve them. Remember, merge conflicts are not bad. They are not an error condition. They are not a problem. They merely indicate that what's happened is beyond Git's capacity to perform automatic merge. Merge conflicts are a good thing: they greatly reduce the chances that Git will do something wrong while merging for you.

Comment: git rebase -i give me the noop message nothing to pick/squash

Comment: You should add the hash commit of `A` after the command (i will edit it soon)

Comment: I tried that also which show all commits so i can pick them but you have to pick the commit A and squash B,C,D and E. Until that point it works but the result is merge conflict on applying the commit A...

Comment: What connflict occurs?

Comment: merge conflict: Could not apply A..initial commit

Comment: Can you please share your remote repo? It will be very helpful. If it is a private repo you can add me, My user on GitHub is @Yedidyar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244939/discussion-between-y-rashi-and-emkaroly).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward. Assuming the following history:

```
4103511 (HEAD -> master) H - add stuff
7946283 G - add stuff
f78ffc7 F - add stuff
ced1bdc E - remove big files
1234ee9 D - add stuff
b9fd6c6 C - add big files
af5a768 B - add stuff
a1436d0 A - Initial commit
```

then you can:

1. Create a new branch from `F`:

   `$ git checkout -b newbranch f78ffc7`
2. Squash all commits into one on `newbranch` (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23486788/3390419) for the tip):

   `$ git reset $(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -m "F - add stuff")`
3. Cherry-pick commits `G` and `H` from `master`:

   `$ git cherry-pick 7946283`
   `$ git cherry-pick 4103511`

you'll end up with a new branch `newbranch` which contains the desired history:

```
1fafbe7 (HEAD -> newbranch) H - add stuff
4e9d879 G - add stuff
7bc7b56 F - add stuff
```