# Notepad++ error when doing git pull

Tags: git, notepad++

When doing a git pull I got the following error:

[image]

The error text is: "line 0: syntax error near unexpected token '('

I have done a git pull on this machine once before successfully.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the output of `git config --show-origin -l`: there might be an editor registered with the wrong syntax (for instance, without the proper quotes or escape characters), which are causing the path in a git configuration to be problematic.

Edit the right config (system, global or local) with `git config --edit`, and remove the incorrect setting.

Check "[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/773973/6309)": since [Git (for Windows)](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) 2.5.3+, a simple `git config core.editor notepad` should be enough.

Or, for notepad++:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Comment: This turned out to be the problem, an unquoted path to the exe. The line in the .gitconfig should read: editor = "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'"