# Why can't I set notepad++ as my git commit editor in Windows 10?

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I know this question has been asked and answered more than once. But I tried at least ten different ways of doing it suggested by the answers and none of them work for me. I always get `nano` as the editor when I do

```
git commit
```

(This would not be such a big problem if I could cut and paste into `nano`, but it can't be done)

Just as an example, here are the lines in my `.gitconfig` file, but please bear in mind I tried many variations of this:

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```ini
[core]
    editor = \"C:/Program Files (x86)/notepad++/notepad++.exe\" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

or from command line:

```sh
git config --global core.editor '"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe" -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin'
```

PS: You could also install [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) that will help you set it...

Comment: @Thanks for the suggestion, but that does not work either. I installed GitExtensions, which is for Visual Studio. I am not using Git from within Visual Studio.

Comment: Gitextensions is not linked to visual Studio. Does it put the setting well? . Put notepad directory in the PATH, that way you could remove the path from the config. And what is the error returned by git?

Comment: I had downloaded GitExtensionsVSIX.vsix, that is why I thought it was for Visual Studio. Now I downloaded a zip file that contains what looks like a Visual Studio solution. There is a GitExtensions.sln file among many other files and folders. But I do not know what to do with it. Should I compile an executable using Visual Studio? On your last question, when I try to commit and get nano instead of notepad++ there are no error messages. All that happens is that nano starts.

Comment: You should have 2 config key. Use `git config --list --show-origin | grep editor` to diagnostic why. That's the `.msi` file (it's the extension name of installers on Windows) of GitExtensions that you should download

Answer (score 4):

It isn't elegant but this worked for me (enclose double-quotes with single-quotes):

```
git config --global core.editor '"C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"'
```

Comment: The key to this is the nested quotation marks.  Doesn't matter whether single quotes are the outer set or inner, you just need to have them nested.

Answer (score 2):

After unsuccessfully trying all the suggestions mentioned earlier, finally

`git config --global core.editor "'C:\\Program Files\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'"`

worked for me.
If Notepad++ installation is on Program Files (x86) the command should be

```
git config --replace-all --global core.editor "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe'"
```