# Unknown function error when opening Vim with 'git commit' command but not with 'vim' command

Tags: git, vim, command-line

When I open Vim from the command line with `vim`, my _vimrc file runs without an error. When `git commit` opens vim as its editor, the following error occurs:

```
C:\dev\settings>git commit                                                                   
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file... 
Error detected while processing /c/Users/me/_vimrc:
line    1:                                                                 
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect                                    
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()        
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Why does `pathogen#infect()` cause an error when git opens vim? How do we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git ships with its own copy of Vim, and that one is built with Unix-style paths, so it looks for your plugins (like Pathogen) in `~/.vim/` instead of `~/vimfiles`.

Duplicating your configuration is one way to solve it, but then you'll have to maintain both in parallel. I think a better approach is to make all Vim versions use the same configuration, by adapting the `'runtimepath'` inside your `~/.vimrc`. The following fragment (to be put at the top of your `~/.vimrc`) will make Windows use the Unix-style paths:

```
" On Windows, also use ~/.vim instead of ~/vimfiles; this makes synchronization
" across (heterogeneous) systems easier.
if has('win32') || has('win64')
    let &runtimepath = substitute(&runtimepath, '\C\V' . escape($HOME.'/vimfiles', '\'), escape($HOME.'/.vim', '\&'), 'g')
    if exists('&packpath')
        let &packpath = &runtimepath
    endif
endif
```

Comment: That seems more precise than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated in [issue 687](https://github.com/python-mode/python-mode/issues/687), that means vim, as executed in a git bash context, does not recognize pathogen.

- [`vim-pathogen`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) might help
- but another alternative on Windows is to [configure your editor to anything else but vim](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564/6309).

Answer (score 1):

Based on VonC's suggestion, my initial fix was to have both `~/.vim` and `~/vimfiles`.

```
PS> Copy-Item ~\vimfiles\ ~\.vim -Recurse
```