# Git PhpStorm - cannot close commit dialog

Tags: git, phpstorm, editor, git-commit, jetbrains-ide

This is a pretty simple scenario. In [PhpStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) **v2018.3** while using git, if I commit anything then the built in terminal there says it is waiting for the user to close the dialog to be popped up now. The dialogue window pops up and  lets me add a message regarding the commit. And at the end of the message dialogue, I see the lines :

```
^G Get Help      ^O Write Out     ^W Where Is      ^K Cut Text      ^J Justify       ^C Cur Pos       M-U Undo         M-A Mark Text    M-] To Bracket
^X Exit          ^R Read File     ^\ Replace       ^U Paste Text    ^T To Spell      ^_ Go To Line    M-E Redo         M-6 Copy Text    ^Q Where Was
```

I typed both `^X` and `exit` and then hit the `Enter` key but the dialogue window does not close. How can I close that ?

**EDIT:**
 I am adding a screenshot of the PhpStorm Editor in the mentioned scenario. **Open the image in a new tab to see it in large view.**
[image]

Comment: Does event log indicate anything ? I have tried to reproduce this on a different jetbrains-ide "pycharm", and it works fine, Probably restarting the ide helps and by typing this `^X`, you mean this right `Ctrl+X` ?

Comment: does ^X mean  Ctrl+X ? Yes after using Ctrl+X, I got the message : 'Save modified buffers ?' with Yes . No and cancel option. I opted for Yes and the dialogue window disappeared ? What do the 3 options mean actually ? Can you post your solution as an answer ?

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be using git-for-windows with the default editor settings ([GNU nano](https://www.nano-editor.org/)). You can change the default editor to the editor which you are comfortable with (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10564/10155936)).

To exit the GNU nano editor you need to use the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

The [documentation](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nano.html) for the GNU nano editor states :

> Commands are given by using the Control key (Ctrl, shown as ^) or the Meta key (Alt or Cmd, shown as M-).

Regarding this,

> after using Ctrl+X, I got the message : 'Save modified buffers ?' with Yes . No and cancel option. I opted for Yes and the dialogue window disappeared ? What do the 3 options mean actually ?

It is basically asking whether you want to save the changes (made in the editor for the file) or not. If you opt for `Yes` it does, if you opt for `No` it doesn't and if you opt for `Cancel` it goes back to the editor.