# Unable to do git rebase in Windows cmd

Tags: powershell, git-rebase

I tried to do a git rebase but this is what I got

```
PS > git rebase -i HEAD~38
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...       0 [main] vim 1761 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to vim.exe.stackdump
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/bdd-automation.
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: A problem with the `editor` entry in your `.gitconfig` ?.

Comment: @JPBlanc where do I start looking?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It happens with every command related to editor opening. Doing `git commit` (without -m option) or `git rebase -i <brach>` it gives the same error message, when the editor is set to vim (default). By changing the editor to notepad, it gives the error `error: There was a problem with the editor 'notepad'.`. So, it is related to any command that try to open the editor (I'm using windows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have quite a [few exceptions with `cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile`](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Agit-for-windows%2Fgit+cygwin_exception%3A%3Aopen_stackdumpfile&type=issues)

[`git-for-windows/git` issue 3265](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3265#issuecomment-909799011) refers to "[How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431003/6309)"

`git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"`

So try first and set your editor to a new one, and see if the issue persists.