# unable to set notepad++ as editor for git in PowerShell

Tags: git, notepad++

I'm using Powershell ISE on a 64-bit Windows machine and when I type:

`git config --list --show-origin` I go down to the `core.editor` section and see:

`core.editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin`

as is suggested here: [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

However, when I type `git commit` hoping for the editor to open, I get the following error:

```
git : error: cannot spawn notepad++: No such file or directory
At line:1 char:1
+ git commit
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error: cannot s...le or directory:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
 
error: unable to start editor 'notepad++'
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

So the error seems to be telling me I don't have notepad++ when I definitely do.  Please help.  I've been looking around for a while and have been unable to make any progress.

Comment: You could reinstall git. There is an option to choose the default text editor tool. I choosed VS Code.

Comment: Tried this, still didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what git version you have, you should have in the .gitconfig an entry like this

```
[core]
    editor = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin
```

instead of something like

```
core.editor = 'C:/Pr....
```

but to be sure, you can run in the powershell directly the command:

```
git config --global core.editor "myEditor"
```

no matter which version of git you use, git will write it right in the config file...

in your case:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"
```

Comment: i tried reinstalling git and notepad++ but i get the same error.  my computer is behind a firewall would that matter?